# Convert DateTime to timezone, set time and convert back

Tags: java, jodatime

I have a little utility method which converts a `DateTime` to a specific `DateTimeZone`, sets the time in that time zone and converts to another timezone again:

```
/**
 * Delivers a DateTime with changed time in the specified DateTimeZone.
 *
 * @param  dateTime      the date time to convert
 * @param  hour          the hour to set in the client timezone date time
 * @param  minute        the minute to set in the client timezone date time
 * @param  second        the second to set in the client timezone date time
 * @param  dtzConversion the client time zone
 * @param  dtzReturn     the time zone of the return date time (optionally: can be null)
 * @return the date time
 */
public DateTime convertDateTimeToTimeZone(final DateTime dateTime, final int hour, final int minute, final int second,
                                          final DateTimeZone dtzConversion, final DateTimeZone dtzReturn)
{
    // convert to given timezone        
    DateTime dtClientTimezone = dateTime.withZoneRetainFields(dtzConversion);
    // adjust time
    dtClientTimezone = dtClientTimezone.withTime(hour, minute, second, 0);

    if (dtzReturn != null) {
        // convert to target timezone
        dtClientTimezone = dtClientTimezone.withZoneRetainFields(dtzReturn);
    }

    return dtClientTimezone;
}
```

In my example `dateTime` is the german date `30.9.2015 22:00:00 UTC` and `dtzConversion` is `Europe/Berlin` and `dtzReturn` is `UTC` with time to set `12:00:00` the result is 30.09.2015 12:00:00. But I would expect the 01.10.2015 10:00:00 because `30.09.2015 22:00:00 UTC` to `Europe/Berlin` should be `01.10.2015 00:00:00`. The the time is set to '12:00:00' which results in `01.10.2015 12:00:00`. This in `UTC` is `01.10.2015 10:00:00`. Where is my fault?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method [`withZoneRetainFields`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withZoneRetainFields%28org.joda.time.DateTimeZone%29) does not convert the fields values. Instead, it just changes the timezone (and the underlying milliseconds so that the fields have the same values in the new timezone as in the old one).

The method you are searching for is [`withZone`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withZone%28org.joda.time.DateTimeZone%29), which adjusts the fields:

```
public static DateTime convertDateTimeToTimeZone(final DateTime dateTime, final int hour, final int minute,
        final int second,
        final DateTimeZone dtzConversion, final DateTimeZone dtzReturn)
{
    // convert to given timezone        
    DateTime dtClientTimezone = dateTime.withZone(dtzConversion);
    // adjust time
    dtClientTimezone = dtClientTimezone.withTime(hour, minute, second, 0);

    if (dtzReturn != null) {
        // convert to target timezone
        dtClientTimezone = dtClientTimezone.withZone(dtzReturn);
    }

    return dtClientTimezone;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    DateTime parse = DateTime.parse("2015-09-30T22:00:00Z");
    DateTime convertDateTimeToTimeZone = convertDateTimeToTimeZone(parse, 12, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.forOffsetHours(2), DateTimeZone.UTC);
    System.out.println(convertDateTimeToTimeZone);
}
```

Result:

> 2015-10-01T10:00:00.000Z

Comment: Seems right. But why the first timezone conversion the time millis are the same? `DateTime dtClientTimezone = dateTime.withZone(dtzConversion);` with `dateTime` millis is 1443650400000 (30.09.2015 22:00:00) and `dtzConversion` is 'Europe/Berlin', now `dtClientTimezone` millis are also 1443650400000. Why? The millis should be 2 hours greater. Isn't it?

Comment: Maybe the timezone of `datetime` was set to German timezone then no adjustment would be taken. Updated the code with an example.

Comment: Do you mean such like al local time zone? In my case it happens on the server so I only want to convert these millis to a specific time zone. I am a little bit confused with joda time.

Comment: Yes, if you use DateTime.now(), a constructor without `DateTimeZone` paramter or parse a String without a timezone/offset, the DateTime object is created with the system's timezone.

Comment: If you are reading datetime from a source not providing a timezone, you should consinder using the `LocalDate[Time]` classes. These are build to represent date/time values without timezones. When it comes to timezones, the user is explicitly forced to think about correct handling. It seems to me, that your method is build to meet exactly this requirement.

Comment: The dateTime which shall be converted is always UTC. In the 1st step I want to convert it to another time zone (client time zone) with also the millis. But when I read the javadoc withZone() method should change the millis, but does not :(

Comment: Difficult to explain without a whiteboard ;-) I think you are missing the link between `Instant`, `LocalDateTime` and `DateTime`. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437550/java-8-whats-the-difference-between-instant-and-localdatetime. This holds true also for joda time (where DateTime is like ZonedDateTime).