# Which java.time type best fits for auditing information?

Tags: datetime, time, timestamp, java-8

In our new (Java 8 based) application we want to store auditing information like `lastModifiedAt` and `createdAt`.

Currently these properties have a `java.sql.Timestamp` type, *representing a moment in time (UTC)*. The new application does not use a SQL database anymore and we want to make use of the new `java.time` API.

What type fits best?

- [Instant](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html). Reading the JavaDoc, it is meant for these use cases: "This class models a single instantaneous point on the time-line. This might be used to record event time-stamps in the application."
- [LocalDateTime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/time/LocalDateTime.html) as this is mapped to `java.sql.Timestamp` according to this [Oracle Technology Network article, Java SE 8 Date and Time](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html)
- Just keep `java.sql.Timestamp`. Because what advantages do the new `java.time` types offer **in this use case**? `java.sql.Timestamp` is more efficient (less object creation).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go for Instant. The new java.time api is just better to use, if you do any further processing of your timestamp (Thread-safety, immutability).

java.sql.Timestamp is only a Wrapper for java.util.Date with the additional nanosecond information, so it inherits also all the disadvantages of java.util.Date. In terms of speed, I have just done a small test for the three types:

```
public void test() {
    Instant ref = Instant.now();
    Instant inst = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        inst = Instant.now();
    }
    System.out.println(Duration.between(ref, Instant.now()));
    ref = Instant.now();
    LocalDateTime ldt = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        ldt = LocalDateTime.now();
    }
    System.out.println(Duration.between(ref, Instant.now()));
    ref = Instant.now();
    Timestamp ts = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
        ts = new Timestamp((new Date()).getTime());
    }
    System.out.println(Duration.between(ref, Instant.now()));
}
```

On my machine results are:

- Instant: 0.188 s
- LocalDateTime: 1.856 s
- Timestamp: 0.173 s

So Instant is faster to instantiate compared to LocalDateTime. Which type to use might also depend on where and how you want to store the data.

**EDIT**
There is another problem with using LocalDateTime:

> If you live in Germany and create a LocalDateTime instance and someone
>   else lives in USA and creates another instance at the very same moment
>   (provided the clocks are properly set) - the value of those objects
>   would actually be different. This does not apply to Instant, which is
>   calculated independently from time zone.

Quoted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32437995/2249614). The same issue might occur when changing to daylight-saving time.