# Query on Date only with Spring Boot Data JPA / Java 8 Instant?

Tags: java, date, jpa, spring-boot, java.time.instant

I have a Spring boot 1.4.x application that uses the starter jpa in combination with H2/Postgresql. I have an entity that stores a date as an Instant (with Instant.now(), based on [Java 8: What's the difference between Instant and LocalDateTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437550/java-8-whats-the-difference-between-instant-and-localdatetime) answer), and the associated table stores this field as a timestamp.

For the storing to work I had to setup a converter that converts Instant's to sql.Timestamps & vice versa, which seems to work (Timestamp.from(instant) and timestamp.toInstant())

My question is if there is a straightforward way to query by Date only using this instant using JPA repository, eg.

`List<Orders> findBySaleTime(.... day)`

Or am I forced to find a way to convert the day to two instants & do an in between query?

Comment: If my answer was helpful and works, please mark it as a solution. Otherwise tell me, so I'll look for another answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are two approaches:

1st one:

```
List<Orders> findBySaleTimeBetween(DateTime start, DateTime end);
```

2nd one:

```
List<Orders> findBySaleTime(DateTime date);
```

It's worth trying to save dates rounded as much as possible, so if you only need day, set hours and minutes to certain values for all the entities.

Comment: This looks like java 7 dates?

Comment: I see, you want to pass Java 8 date... Why can't you make an adapter in your service?

Comment: What do I need to adapt, java 8 -> java 7 date? That would be a bit silly no?

Comment: No? In Java 7 you did all those walkarounds with Date and Calendar. Why not to adapt now. I'll search for a direct solution, but I would mind using adapter. The efficiency of the application doesn't rely on it. There is hibernate-java8, but I wouldn't use it yet. In hibernate 5.2 it's available by default

Answer (score 3):

```
public List<SaleOrder> findByDate(String date) {
    Instant startOfDay = Instant.parse(date).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
    Instant endOfDay = startOfDay.plus(Duration.ofDays(1));

    return saleOrderRepository.findBySaleTimeAfterAndSaleTimeBefore(startOfDay, endOfDay);
}
```

Where the date is an UTC date passed from the client, seems to be the most straightforward to do this with java 8 dates. (Credits to Liste & Yawkat on freenode #java for help/pointers)