# Why java 8 has now method in LocalDateTime class

Tags: date, java-8, java-time

As we aware that, in java we can use existing API's to get the current date and time, compare to that what is the difference between the new LocalDateTime class now() method.

Comment: Because it returns the new type?

Comment: In questions of the style, "What is the difference between X and Y?" It usually helps if you tell us BOTH X and Y - not just X.

Comment: See similar Question, [*What's the difference between Instant and LocalDateTime?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32437550/642706)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

- If referring to `Date`, `Calendar`, and `SimpleDateFormat`, those are terrible old classes, now legacy. **Never use.**
- Use only the modern [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.
- `LocalDateTime` **cannot** represent a moment, as it purposely lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So `LocalDateTime.now` is of no practical use.
- Capture the current moment using [`Instant.now`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#now--) for UTC, or [`ZonedDateTime.now`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#now--) for a particular time zone.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

If by “existing API's” you meant the old date-time classes such as `Date`, `Calendar`, and `SimpleDateFormat`, you should avoid those. While they were well-intentioned industry-leading attempts at date-time handling, they proved to be poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome. They are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system).

## Use java.time

Instead, use the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Added to Java 8 and later. Much of the functionality was back-ported to Java 6 & 7 & Android as well.

### `Local…` types

The “Local…” classes lack any concept of [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) or [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone). As such, they are only a vague idea about possible moments. Without an offset or zone the have no real meaning.

An example of a local date-time is when Christmas begins, 2016-12-25T00:00:00. That does not determine a specific point on the timeline until we apply an offset or zone. Christmas starts earlier in the east. That is why [Santa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santa_Claus) starts his deliveries in the Pacific such as midnight in Auckland NZ and works his way towards Asia with its later midnight, then flies the reindeer on to India after its midnight begins later, and so on westwards.

## `LocalDateTime` not often used

[image]

So while there might be use-cases for calling [`now`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#now-java.time.ZoneId-) on [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html), I cannot imagine one.

The main use for `LocalDateTime` is in parsing strings that lack any indication of offset or zone. Such strings are poorly designed as they are incomplete. Would you communicate a price without specifying the currency? So too it is unwise to specify a date and a time but no offset/zone. At any rate, when you do have such strings lacking offset/zone, parse with `LocalDateTime`.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2016-01-23T12:34:56.789" );
```

If you know the intended offset because of your given scenario, apply it.

```
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.ofHours( -7 );
OffsetDateTime odt = ldt.atOffset( offset );  // Now we have a moment, a specific point on the timeline.
```

Better yet, if you know the time zone because of your given scenario use that instead of an offset. A zone is an offset *plus* the set of rules for handling anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST).

```
ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( zone );  // Now we have a moment, a specific point on the timeline.
```

In common business apps we tend to care about precise moments: When did the invoice arrive, When does the contract expire, Appointment start time, and such. For such point-on-the-timeline values, we use [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html), [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html), and [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). Search *Stack Overflow* for many examples and more discussion. Each of these offer a `now` method. Calling their `now` method retains the important offset/zone info while capturing the current moment. In contrast, calling **`LocalDateTime.now` discards that offset/zone info** intentionally, rarely what you want.

**Tip:** Always pass the optional offset or zone argument to `now`.
If omitted you are relying implicitly on the JVM’s current default time zone being applied. This default can be changed at any moment during runtime by any code on any app within that JVM. Better to specify explicitly your desired/expected offset or zone. IMHO, that optional argument should have been required to remind programmers that they must be always be consciously aware of time zone.

## Current moment

[image]

Capture the current moment in UTC using `Instant`.

May be captured in a resolution as fine as nanoseconds but more likely microseconds or milliseconds depending on limitations of your JVM implementation, your host hardware clock, and your host OS.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture current moment in UTC.
```

[image]

Adjust from UTC to the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Casablanca" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Or, as a shortcut, skip the `Instant` part.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

If the zone argument is omitted, the JVM’s current default time zone is applied implicitly. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).