# Serialize LocalDate and LocalDateTime as Unix timestamps

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson, java-time

I'm moving from using `java.sql.Timestamp` and `java.util.GregorianCalendar` to employ `java.time.*` new classes in a Spring MVC application.

So I changed every

```
private GregorianCalendar field;
```

to

```
private LocalDate field;
```

or

```
private LocalDateTime field;
```

But now when serializing those beans, they get serialized like this:

```
"field": {
      "year": 1970,
      "month": "JANUARY",
      "dayOfMonth": 18,
      "dayOfWeek": "SUNDAY",
      "era": "CE",
      "dayOfYear": 18,
      "leapYear": false,
      "monthValue": 1,
      "chronology": {
        "id": "ISO",
        "calendarType": "iso8601"
      }
    },
```

I found answers to other questions that mention to add a dependency to [jackson-datatype-jsr310](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|a%3A%22jackson-datatype-jsr310%22) and obtained:

```
 "field": [
      1970,
      1,
      18
    ],
```

but I still want a unix timestamp when serializing like I got with `GregorianCalendar` fields: how can I achieve that? Can I avoid a custom serializer (and deserializer)?

These are relevant for resource responses and request bodies (as in POST, PUT, etc), not for request parameters.

The Jackson `ObjectMapper` is configured like so:

```
jacksonConverter.getObjectMapper().enable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
jacksonConverter.getObjectMapper().disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS);
```

Comment: Please let me know if [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51299297/2032415) has helped you (or if hasn't, let me know why).

Comment: @TomaszLinkowski Of course I will, as soon as I get back to the project where I need it :-)

Answer (score 3):

In the JavaDoc to [JavaTimeModule](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-modules-java8/javadoc/datetime/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/JavaTimeModule.html) (included in `jackson-datatype-jsr310` library), we can read the following:

> Most `java.time` types are serialized as numbers (integers or decimals as appropriate) if the `SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS` feature is enabled [...]
>
> [...] If `SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS` is disabled, timestamps are written as a whole number of milliseconds. [...]

and then:

> Some exceptions to this standard serialization/deserialization rule:
>
> - [...]
> - `LocalDate`, `LocalTime`, `LocalDateTime`, and `OffsetTime`, which cannot portably be converted to timestamps and are instead represented as arrays when `WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS` is enabled.

You can indeed see that `LocalDateTime` cannot be ubiquitously converted to the Unix timestamp because its [toEpochSecond](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoLocalDateTime.html#toEpochSecond-java.time.ZoneOffset-) method takes `ZoneOffset` as parameter.

**To sum up**, it seems the best thing you can do is replacing `LocalDateTime` with `Instant` (see [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437550/whats-the-difference-between-instant-and-localdatetime/32443004#32443004) for an explanation of the difference between `LocalDateTime` and `Instant`).

Other than that, you would indeed need custom `JsonSerializer` and `JsonDeserializer`.

---

Here's a working code sample:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
            .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule())
            .disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS);

    Entity entity = new Entity(Instant.now());

    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    objectMapper.writeValue(writer, entity);
    System.out.println(writer.getBuffer());
}

@lombok.Value
static class Entity {
    Instant timestamp;
}
```