# How to configure Jackson to convert all fields of a type to another type?

Tags: java, jackson

If I have a POJO field of type `A` that I want serialized as being of type `B`, I can easily achieve this with a pair of `Converter`s:

```
@JsonSerialize(converter=ConvA2B.class)
@JsonDeserialize(converter=ConvB2A.class)
private A field;
```

But what if I want all the fields of that type in all the POJOs to be treated like that? Is there a global converters configuration?

---

To provide a bit of context, I'm trying to [serialize `java.time.LocalDateTime` fields as unix timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51284630/3127111) and one possible solution I found is to convert each field to `java.time.Instant` with a custom type converter such as:

```
public static class Conv extends StdConverter<LocalDateTime, Instant> {

    @Override
    public Instant convert(LocalDateTime value) {
        return value.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm thinking of using a custom `AnnotationIntrospector`. Did you find any other solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the `ObjectMapper` that Jackson uses. In general, you can configure how you want to serialize certain types. For your concrete problem, you could try the following:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jsr310.JavaTimeModule;

...

private ObjectMapper createObjectMapper() {
    final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    return mapper;
}
```

Now, depending on your application setup, you need to inject/supply/configure the object mapper somewhere.