# How to configure Jackson's Object Mapper to use type converter globally for all deserializations?

Tags: java, jackson

I need to convert certain values in json body of all my http requests.
Specifically, the client will send string `"null"` instead of null reference for `String` properties and `0` for `int` properties.

example json body of request

```
{
  "name": "null",
  "age": "null"
}
```

needs to be deserialized into

```
public class Person {
    public String name;  // name == null
    public int age;      // age == 0
}
```

Initially I added custom String Deserializer to ObjectMapper:

```
@Bean
public Module convertNullValueToNullReference() {
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addDeserializer(String.class, new StdDeserializer<>(String.class) {
        @Override
        public String deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
            String value = StringDeserializer.instance.deserialize(p, context);
            if ("null".equalsIgnoreCase(value)) {
                return null;
            }
            return value;
        }
    });
    return module;
}
```

but this obviously does not work for the case of int fields. I need to add type converter to `ObjectMapper` but there is no `addConverter()` method in `SimpleModule`.

I know about `@JsonDeserialize(converter = ...)` but I need to register the converter globally for all classes.

I searched SO and could only find [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51287906/how-to-configure-jackson-to-convert-all-fields-of-a-type-to-another-type) but the answer is tailored to the specific conversion of dates and is not suitable for my case

Comment: what I see is "null" is mapped to 0 by default, or you need value other than 0?

Comment: I'm not a 100% sure, as I only used basic Jackson until now, but i guess adding an extra deserializer for Integer.class could work?

Comment: @samabcde, from experience, string "null" is not mapped to 0. value causes exception

Comment: I tried this in springboot application and it prints `null 0`. `Person p = objectMapper.readValue(new StringReader("""
                {
                  "name": "null",
                  "age": "null"
                }
                """), Person.class);
        System.out.println(p.name + " " + p.age);`

Answer (score -1):

To register a Jackson Converter globally, you can either embed it into a deserializer, or into an annotation introspector. For more details and examples, see

https://enji.systems/2023/03/16/jsonb-adapter-jackson-converter.html