# JPA: compare LocalDateTime attribute to builder.currentTimestamp()

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Given:

```
@Entity
public class Paramter() {
  @Id
  private Long id;
  private LocalDateTime startDate;
  // getters & setters
}

// Extract from repository/dao method that grabs parameters:
...
final CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery<Parameter> query = builder.createQuery(Parameter.class);
final Root<Parameter> param = query.from(Parameter);

// The line below is generates following compilation error due to mismatch 
// of the types of LocalDateTime and Timestamp parameters: 
// java: no suitable method found for greaterThanOrEqualTo(javax.persistence.criteria.Path<java.time.LocalDateTime>,javax.persistence.criteria.Expression<java.sql.Timestamp>)
query.where(builder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(param.get(Parameter_.startDate), builder.currentTimestamp()));     ...
```

How to properly use java 8 date-time api (more specifically LocalDateTime property) with jpa criteria builder to achive: "select * from parameter where start_date >= sysdate"?
Please consider:

- The solution can be Oracle specific but should use JPA criteria builder
- I do not want to create a select query to grab the sysdate and than use it in another select query to grab the valid parameters. It should be done in one query like in the expected query example above.
- The time from the server is not reliable - database time should be used

Using Hibernate 5.2.16 which seems to include JPA 2.1. Changing to JPA 2.2 doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Never use `LocalDateTime` for a moment. That class lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So it represents *potential* moments along a range of about 26-27 hours, the range of time zones. For a moment, use `Instant` (always in UTC), or `ZonedDateTime` (holds a time zone), or less commonly, `OffsetDateTime` (holds an offset-from-UTC). See [Question on the difference between Instant and LocalDateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32437550/642706).