# LocalDateTime getting updated by 4 hours everyTime I do repository.save()

Tags: java, datetime

I am trying to update the class test in JAVA . 
Here when I am trying to update it as shown below It always adds 4 hours to the created Date. I am doing something like this. I am using LocalDateTime for createdDate. I think 4 hours is because of the Zone.

Any help is appreciated. Please let me know.

Thanks in Advance. :)

```
    public Test updateTest(TestDTO testDTO, Employee employee) throws 
     TransactionSystemException {
    Test test = TestRepository.findOne(testDTO.getId());

    Test returnTest = null;

    testDTO = (TestDTO) CustomData.convertData(testDTO);

    test.setTestDate(testDTO.getTestDate());
    if(testDTO.getCreatedDate() != null){
       test.setCreatedDate(test.getCreatedDate());
    }
    test.setCreatedBy(test.getCreatedBy());
    test.setTestProcedureId(testDTO.getTestProcedureId());
    test.setCollectionSiteType(testDTO.getCollectionSiteType());
    test.setMobileId(testDTO.getMobileId());

    returnTest = TestRepository.save(test);

    return returnTest;
    }

    // Test Domain
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "test")
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
    public class Test implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 30)
    @Column(name = "id", length=30)
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "created_date")
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;

    @Column(name="created_by")
    private Long createdBy;

    @Column(name="test_procedure_id", nullable = false)
    private Long testProcedureId;

    @Column(name="collection_site_type", nullable = false)
    private String collectionSiteType;

    @Column(name="mobile_id")
    private Long mobileId;

     @Column(name = "updated_date")
     private LocalDateTime updatedDate;
    // --------------------- GETTER / SETTER METHODS ---------------------

    public String getId() {
    return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getTestProcedureId() {
    return testProcedureId;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getCreatedDate() {
    return createdDate;
    }

    public void setCreatedDate(LocalDateTime createdDate) {
    this.createdDate = createdDate;
    }

    public Long getCreatedBy() {
    return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(Long createdBy) {
    this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public void setTestProcedureId(Long testProcedureId) {
        this.testProcedureId = testProcedureId;
    }

    public String getCollectionSiteType() {
        return collectionSiteType;
    }

    public void setCollectionSiteType(String collectionSiteType) {
        this.collectionSiteType = collectionSiteType;
    }

    public Long getMobileId() {
        return mobileId;
    }

    public void setMobileId(Long mobileId) {
           this.mobileId = mobileId;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getUpdatedDate() {
        return updatedDate;
    }

    public void setUpdatedDate(LocalDateTime updatedDate) {
        this.updatedDate = updatedDate;
    }
    }
```

Comment: I doubt that would even compile

Comment: that is just to show that I am passing the same value but always the updated value is adding 4 hours to it.

Comment: If you want someone to help you fix the code, you should post the code that's causing the problem, not some other code which is not related to the problem.

Comment: What does `setCreatedDate()` do? What does `getCreatedDate()` do? What does `save()` do? They are all potential sources of the issue.

Comment: Please post the original code.

Comment: And please fix the formatting

Comment: I formatted the code now. Thank you :)

Comment: @ClintMunden I did. TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.now()  // Capture current moment in UTC.
```

## Use `Instant`,  not `LocalDateTime`

You do not post the relevant code so we cannot say for certain. But likely you are mishandling time zone. And you are certainly using the wrong class.

The `LocalDateTime` class cannot represent a moment as it lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC.  So this class is irrelevant to your purpose of logging events.

Instead use `Instant`. This class represents a moment in UTC, always in UTC by definition.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

To adjust into a time zone, such as for display to the user, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

See another Question, [*What's the difference between Instant and LocalDateTime?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32437550/642706)

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html  <-- try ZonedDateTime or just util.Date.

Comment: The terrible `java.util.Date` class was supplanted years ago by the modern `java.time.Instant` class. No need to ever use that again, except to inter-operate with old code not yet update to the *java.time* classes.