# How can I convert a time in milliseconds to ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, java-time

I have the time in milliseconds and I need to convert it to a ZonedDateTime object.

I have the following code

```
long m = System.currentTimeMillis();
LocalDateTime d = LocalDateTime.millsToLocalDateTime(m);
```

The line

```
LocalDateTime d = LocalDateTime.millsToLocalDateTime(m);
```

gives me a error saying 
methed millsToLocalDateTime is undefined for type LocalDateTime

Comment: There is no such method in JDK. Maybe you were using JodaTime

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`ZonedDateTime` and `LocalDateTime` are [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437550/whats-the-difference-between-instant-and-localdatetime/32443004#32443004).

If you need `LocalDateTime`, you can do it this way:

```
long m = ...;
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(m);
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

Answer (score 19):

You can construct a `ZonedDateTime` from an instant (this uses the system zone ID):

```
//Instant is time-zone unaware, the below will convert to the given zone
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(m), 
                                ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

And if you need a `LocalDateTime` instance from that:

```
//And this date-time will be "local" to the above zone
LocalDateTime ldt = zdt.toLocalDateTime();
```

Answer (score 14):

Whether you want a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html), [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html), [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html), or [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html), the syntax is really the same, and all revolves around applying the milliseconds to an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) first using [`Instant.ofEpochMilli(m)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochMilli-long-).

```
long m = System.currentTimeMillis();

ZonedDateTime  zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(m), ZoneId.systemDefault());
LocalDateTime  ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(m), ZoneId.systemDefault());
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(m), ZoneId.systemDefault());
LocalDate      ld  = LocalDate.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(m), ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

Printing them would produce something like this:

```
2018-08-21T12:47:11.991-04:00[America/New_York]
2018-08-21T12:47:11.991
2018-08-21T12:47:11.991-04:00
2018-08-21
```

Printing the `Instant` itself would produce:

```
2018-08-21T16:47:11.991Z
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create extension methods in Java. If you want to define a separate method for this create a Utility class:

```
class DateUtils{

    public static ZonedDateTime millsToLocalDateTime(long m){
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault();
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(m);
        ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, zoneId);
        return zonedDateTime;
    }
}
```

From your other class call

```
DateUtils.millsToLocalDateTime(89897987989L);
```