# LocalDateTime is not ISO8601 by default

Tags: java, jackson

I'm using `LocalDateTime` to represent time.
In the debugging mode, I noticed that the time format is not in ISO 8601, which makes me hard to send directly to other apis.

Request class：

```
public class AgreementRequest {
    @NonNull
    private String name;
    @NonNull
    private String description;
    @JsonProperty("start_date")
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DATE_TIME)
    @NonNull
    private String startDate;
}
```

Initialization:

```
request = AgreementRequest.builder()
                .name("Premium subscription")
                .description("Montly subscription")
                .startDate(LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(1).toString()).build();
```

[image]

The `LocalDateTime.toString` is not either in ISO 8601, the letter `z` in ISO8601 is gone.

I have `objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);` disabled, is this the problem?

Comment: *"The LocalDateTime.toString is not either in ISO 8601, the letter z in ISO8601 is gone."* Yes, it is. ISO-8601 doesn't require a timezone on strings; the string shown is a perfectly valid ISO-8601 datetime string. If there is no timezone, ISO-8601 assumes "local time." Given that the class is `LocalDateTime`, that representation makes sense.

Comment: The "local" part indicates the LocalDateTime is for a date/time without a timezone.

Comment: Should I use `Instant` instead of `LocalDateTime`? If so, what should I change in my PostgreSQL DB?

Comment: @Cosaic See the [documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/8-date-time.html).

Comment: @Cosaic Use `Instant` for an actual moment, a point on the timeline, in UTC. Use `LocalDateTime` when you mean all time zones or any time zone.  These are completely different animals, not at all interchangeable, because **`LocalDateTime` cannot represent a moment**. See: [*What’s the difference between `Instant` and `LocalDateTime`?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32437550/642706).

Comment: @BasilBourque Your answer is golden. I wish I could upvote it again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The `LocalDateTime.toString` is not either in ISO 8601, the letter `Z` in ISO8601 is gone.

[`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) a description of the date, as used for birthdays, combined with the local time as seen on a wall clock. It cannot represent an instant on the time-line without additional information such as an offset or time-zone.

`Z` is the zone designator for the zero UTC offset and that's why you won't see it when invoking [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#toString()) from a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) instance. Use [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) or [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) if you need a time-zone or an offset.

To (de)serialize [JSR-310](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) types with Jackson, consider the [`JavaTimeModule`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-modules-java8/javadoc/datetime/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jsr310/JavaTimeModule.html). See the [documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8/tree/master/datetime) for details.

---

> Should I use `Instant` instead of `LocalDateTime`? If so, what should I change in my PostgreSQL DB?

Check what the PostgreSQL JDBC driver [documentation](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/query/) says about it:

> The PostgreSQL™ JDBC driver implements native support for the [Java 8 Date and Time API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html) (JSR-310) using JDBC 4.2.
>
> ```
> +--------------------------------+----------------+
> | PostgreSQL™                    | Java SE 8      |
> +--------------------------------+----------------+
> | DATE                           | LocalDate      |
> | TIME [ WITHOUT TIMEZONE ]      | LocalTime      |
> | TIMESTAMP [ WITHOUT TIMEZONE ] | LocalDateTime  |
> | TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE        | OffsetDateTime |
> +--------------------------------+----------------+
> ```
>
> This is closely aligned with tables B-4 and B-5 of the JDBC 4.2 specification.
>
> **Note**
> `ZonedDateTime`, `Instant` and `OffsetTime / TIME [ WITHOUT TIMEZONE ]` are not supported. Also note that all `OffsetDateTime` will instances will have be in UTC (have offset 0). This is because the backend stores them as UTC.

Comment: Or use `Instant` if you always want to use the UTC timezone. `ZonedDateTime`/`OffsetDateTime`s are only useful if you want to use variable timezones. Please note that the actual timezone might be lost if saved to a database such as postgres (only the timestamp in utc is saved). They are supported by (some) JPA implementations.

Comment: If I have an `Instant` in UTC, I then convert it to `LocalDateTime` and store it in DB. Is this a valid process?

Comment: @Cosaic It depends. `Instant` and `LocalDateTime` are different things. Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32443004/1426227) from Basil Bourque.