# Instant vs ZonedDateTime

Tags: postgresql, utc, timestamp-with-timezone, zoneddatetime, java.time.instant

I just do not quite understand which one of those two I should use for the following example:

We have an `OfferEntity` which has a member `availableDay` which is the date at which the offer is available.

Now, the table will look something like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS offer (
  created   timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
  id        BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  available timestamp with time zone
);
```

From the [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#AEN5811) we know that:

> For `timestamp with time zone`, the internally stored value is always in UTC (Universal Coordinated Time, traditionally known as Greenwich Mean Time, GMT). An input value that has an explicit time zone specified is converted to UTC using the appropriate offset for that time zone. If no time zone is stated in the input string, then it is assumed to be in the time zone indicated by the system's `TimeZone` parameter, and is converted to UTC using the offset for the timezone zone.

Which means I should be fine when it comes to persisting any date/time information.

But what does this mean for my `OfferEntity` and the REST endpoints I define in `OfferController`?

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "offer")
public class OfferEntity {    
    @Column(name = "available", nullable = false)
    private ZonedDateTime availableDay;
}
```

vs

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "offer")
public class OfferEntity {    
    @Column(name = "available", nullable = false)
    private Instant availableDay;
}
```

From what I understood - this should not make a difference. PostgreSQL stores everything as UTC anyway so I should be able to take `Instant` or `ZonedDateTime` right? Write something -> UTC. Read it again -> still UTC.

Even the client won't be able to tell the difference:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Object hello() {

    class Hello {
        public Instant instant = Instant.now();
        public ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.now();
        public ZonedDateTime viennaTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("GMT+2"));
        public LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

    return new Hello();
}
```

Will return:

```
{
  "instant":       "2018-10-07T15:30:08.579Z",
  "zonedDateTime": "2018-10-07T15:30:08.579Z",
  "viennaTime":    "2018-10-07T17:30:08.579+02:00",
  "localDateTime": "2018-10-07T15:30:08.579",
}
```

But there must be a crucial difference which I am apparently not seeing.

---

There are two differences I can make out. It seems to be that Spring has no problem with converting `"2018-10-07T15:30:08.579Z"` to an `Instant` object, but fails to do so if I change the type to `ZonedDateTime`. At least out of the box.

```java
@RequestMapping("/places/{placeId}/offers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<OfferDto> getOffers(
        @PathVariable(name = "placeId") Long placeId,
        @RequestParam(name = "date") ZonedDateTime date) {
    return this.offerService.getOffers(placeId, date);
}
```

The other difference is the fact that if I use `Instant` I am forcing my clients to convert all their date/time strings to UTC first. So any client will have to `myDate.toUTCString()` first. `ZonedDateTime` would take anything as long as it has a time zone set but why would we care?

---

So which of the two is the better choice and why would I chose one over the other?

Answer (score 26):

The answer in the following link explains it better than I ever could. The answer goes into all the different date/time classes in Java, as well as their relation to sql types.

[What's the difference between Instant and LocalDateTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437550/whats-the-difference-between-instant-and-localdatetime/32443004#32443004)

A short summary:
The classes Instant and ZonedDateTime (as well as OffsetDateTime)
represent the same thing: a moment in time. The difference is that
ZonedDateTime and OffsetDateTime offer extra context and functionality
about timezones or time offsets, whereas Instant has no timezone or
offset specified. This can lead to differences especially when Daylight Saving Time is involved. For instance, take the following snippet of code:

```
    ZonedDateTime z1 = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.of(2019, 10, 26, 6, 0, 0), ZoneId.of("Europe/Amsterdam"));
    Instant i1 = z1.plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS).toInstant();
    Instant i2 = z1.toInstant().plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
    System.out.println(i1);
    System.out.println(i2);
```

The result will be this:

```
    2019-10-27T05:00:00Z
    2019-10-27T04:00:00Z
```

The difference stems from the fact that in the Amsterdam timezone, the 27th of October has an extra hour. When we convert to Instant the timezone information is lost, so adding a day will add only 24 hours.

LocalDateTime is a different beast alltogether. It represents a date
and time without timezone information. It does *not* represent a
moment in Time. It is useful for writing things such as "Christmas
morning starts at december 25th 00:00:00". This is true regardless of
timezone, and as such a ZonedDateTime or Instant would not be appropriate.