# Remap one date format to another in Java model

Tags: java, json

1) The date format I'm getting from API is `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX`

2) I want to give back a Json list with dates to frontend in different format like: `dd MM HH:mm`

Is there any annotations or properties to remap dates in 2) example as in 1) it's easily achievable with `@JsonFormat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some logic in `getter` (e.g. `getDate()`) like there:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputDate = "2014-07-04T12:08:56.235-07:00";
        String inputFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX";

        String outputFormat = "dd MM HH:mm";

        // Input formatter
        DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(inputFormat);

        // Time after formatting
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(inputDate, inputFormatter);

        // Output formatter
        DateTimeFormatter outputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(outputFormat);

        // Output date as String
        String outputDate = dateTime.format(outputFormatter);

        System.out.println(outputDate);
    }
}
```

Comment: **Incorrect.** `LocalDateTime` is the wrong class to be using here. That class purposely lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. Yet the input carries an offset-from-UTC. Your code here is needlessly discarding valuable information.

Answer (score 2):

## Offset-from-UTC

The `XXX` in your formatting pattern refers to an [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). This means the date and time-of-day represent a moment that is a number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead of, or behind, the baseline of [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

## `OffsetDateTime`

So parse that input with [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2019-01-23T12:34:56.123+05:30" ) ;
```

Do not be mislead into using the [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) class for such inputs. This class purposely lacks any concept of [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). So this class *cannot* be used to represent a moment. Parsing your inputs with this class is recklessly discarding valuable information. See: [*What's the difference between Instant and LocalDateTime?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32437550/642706)

[image: Table of types of date-time class in modern java.time versus legacy]

### `DateTimeFormatter`

To generate strings representing this value in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, merely call [`toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#toString()).

```
String output = odt.toString() ;  // Generate string in standard ISO 8601 format.
```

To generate strings in other formats, use the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class. You can specify a custom format, or better, let the class automatically localize for you.

To localize, specify:

- [`FormatStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) to determine how long or abbreviated should the string be.
- [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html) to determine:

  - The *human language* for translation of name of day, name of month, and such.
  - The *cultural norms* deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, separators, and such.

Example:

```
Locale l = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;   // Or Locale.US, Locale.JAPAN, etc.
DateTimeFormatter f = 
    DateTimeFormatter
    .ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.FULL )
    .withLocale( l )
;
String output = zdt.format( f );
```

[Search Stack Overflow](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com%20java%20%2BDateTimeFormatter&t=osx&ia=web) for more info, as `DateTimeFormatter` has already been covered many many times.

## ISO 8601

Your input strings happen to be in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

The *java.time* classes use these standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).