# How to pass Javascript Date to Java LocalDate and to LocalDateTime in REST with JAX-RS

Tags: javascript, java, angular, rest, jax-rs

When I pass a Javascript Date to a JAX-RS service I receive:

1. In case the target field is LocalDate: Text '2018-06-04T22:00:00.000Z' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 10". The BackEnd is ok with "2018-06-04", I tried with Postman.
2. In case the target field is LocalDateTime: Text '2019-04-02T20:16:24.999Z' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 23. The BackEnd is ok with "2019-04-02T20:16:24", I tried with Postman.

The information i pass to the BackEnd come from a Angular Material Datepicker component that I map on a javascript Date object.

I understand that the string has informations that the BackEnd do not aspect but I don't know how to pass the correct/modified value before call the POST.

Should I pass a String instead of a Date object? Is that the correct approach?

Is there a way from a date in the format "2018-06-04T22:00:00.000Z" or "2018-06-05T00:00:00.000Z" to be passed to a LocalDate and a LocalDateTime?

I used LocalDate and LocalDateTime because I do not want to deal with timezone.
The value are supposed to be always the same even if I change the timezone.

Before I had a problem because there was a 1 hour difference between the server and the client. So when i used to pick a date from the web server it could happen that the client would see the day before on the component becasue it was going back 1 hour from midnight.

Comment: The string `2018-06-04T22:00:00.000Z` can be correctly parsed by `Instant`, `ZonedDateTime` and `OffsetDateTime`. I'd suggest using `ZonedDateTime` for most flexible time zone parsing, and so you can easily obtain `LocalDateTime` and `LocalDate` from it.

Comment: **Warning:** Note that `2018-06-04T22:00:00.000Z` is probably supposed to be `2018-06-05` in a `UTC+02:00` time zone. If so, you'd likely want to apply that time zone first, before obtaining the `LocalDate` and `LocalDateTime` values, so the "local" is appropriate for *that* time zone. --- To do that, I'd suggest using `Instant.parse("2018-06-04T22:00:00.000Z").atOffset(ZoneOffset.of("+2")).toLocalDate()`

Answer (score 7):

You seem to be confusing the various date-time types.

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both legacy and modern.]

## ISO 8601

The string `2018-06-04T22:00:00.000Z` is in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. The `Z` on the end means UTC, and is pronounced *Zulu*.

The ISO 8601 formats are wisely designed. They are easy to parse by machine. And they are easy to read by humans across cultures. Their primary purpose is to communicate date-time values in a textual format. You should indeed be using strings in these formats for exchanging date-time values between systems.

## `Instant`

Parse as an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) in the *java.time* classes.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2018-06-04T22:00:00.000Z" ) ;
```

## `LocalDate`

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset).

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault(java.util.TimeZone)) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly as an argument. If critical, confirm the zone with your user.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `Continent/Region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;  
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the code becomes ambiguous to read in that we do not know for certain if you intended to use the default or if you, like so many programmers, were unaware of the issue.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;  // Get JVM’s current default time zone.
```

So you need to decide by what time zone you want to perceive the moment in UTC as a date and time-of-day.

The ISO 8601 format for a date-only value is YYYY-MM-DD.

```
String output = ld.toString() ;  // Example: 2019-01-23
```

…and…

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2019-01-23" ) ;
```

To generate such a string in JavaScript, see [*Format JavaScript Date to yyyy-mm-dd*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23593052/642706).

## `OffsetDateTime`

If you want `UTC` itself, convert from `Instant` to `OffsetDateTime`. Then extract the date alone.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffsetUTC ) ;  // Convert to the more flexible `OffsetDateTime` class from `Instant` class.
LocalDate ld = odt.toLocalDate() ;                        // Extract a date-only value.
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

If you want a particular time zone, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`. Then extract the date alone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;    // Adjust from UTC to a time zone.
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;           // Extract a date-only value, dropping the time-of-day and the time zone.
```

By the way, note that `ZonedDateTime` class in its `toString` method extends the ISO 8601 format by appending the name of the time zone in square brackets. A wise addition, but may not be handled properly by some other systems.

## `LocalDateTime`

The **`LocalDateTime` class is the *wrong* type** to be using for an input such as `2018-06-04T22:00:00.000Z` or `2019-04-02T20:16:24.999Z`. These string inputs represent a moment, a specific point on the timeline. The `LocalDateTime` class purposely lacks any concept of time zone or offset, so it cannot represent a moment.

People frequently misunderstand the nature of `LocalDateTime`. The “Local” means *any* locality or *every* locality, but not a *particular* locality. For a moment in a specific locality, use `ZonedDateTime`.

For more info, see [*What's the difference between Instant and LocalDateTime?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32437550/642706).

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I know the ones i wrote are instant in the time. That is what Angular Material Datepicker component give me back.
I don't want to use them with timezone. I would like them to never change even if i move to other time zones.
I will explain better in the description