# How to convert Miliseconds in timestamp to Microseconds in timestamp using java

Tags: java, avro

I am have date object and getTime() will return only time in long in miliseconds but i want time in long in microseconds with consideration of timestampmicros concept .
Is there any way for this type of conversion ?
I am having timestamp value that i am getting from mysql DB .
I just want microseconds precision from miliseconds
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is “timestampmicros concept”?

Comment: It's same as mysql timestamp type with precision .

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57419228/1270000

Answer (score 0):

The `java.util.Date` class is terrible and obsolete.

If you want the current moment with a resolution, call `Instant.now()` and truncate the nanoseconds to microseconds.

```
Instant.now().truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.MICROSECONDS )
```