# How to convert long to LocalDateTime?

Tags: java, java-time, epoch, datetime-conversion, localdatetime

I get this field from kafka that use avro schema:

```
long dateTime = 1499070300000L;  //value is just for example, but have to be micros
```

It has logicalType: "logical-timestamp-micros"

And I have this kind of Dto:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yy HH:mm:ss")
  private LocalDateTime time;
```

And I am trying to convert field dateTime to be currentDateTime field format:

```
long dateTime = 1499070300000L;
        DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yy HH:mm:ss");
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(Instant.ofEpochMilli(dateTime)
                .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
                .format(dateTimeFormatter));
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '03.07.17 11:25:00' could not be parsed at index 0
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do not use `LocalDateTime` for a point in time. It does not work. Stick to the `ZonedDateTime` you get from `atZone()`. You can use it for everyting that you can use a `LocalDateTime` for and more. If you need to call an API that requires a `LocalDateTime`,  then pass `yourZonedDateTime.toLocalDateTime()` to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't convert your `ZonedDateTime` to a `String` and back to a `LocalDateTime`.

Instead, use what the API provides.
In your case, [LocalDateTime.ofInstant](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#ofInstant(java.time.Instant,java.time.ZoneId)) seems to be just what you need:

```java
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(dateTime), ZoneId.systemDefault());
```

Aside from that, you meantioned that the timestamp has the type `logical-timestamp-micros`. `Instant.ofEpochMilli` requires milliseconds. If your `long` is actually the time in microseconds, you might want to divide it by 1000 before using it in `Instant.ofEpochMilli`. Alternatively, the `TimeUnit` class can do that conversion for you as [pointed out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74169445/how-to-convert-long-to-localdatetime/74169511?noredirect=1#comment131675827_74169511) by @[Arvind Kumar Avinash](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10819573/arvind-kumar-avinash) like the following:
`TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(milliTime, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)`

If you care about preserving microseconds, you can use `Instant.EPOCH.plus(timeMicros, ChronoUnit.MICROS)` for obtaining the `Instant` instead of using `Instant.ofEpochMilli` as suggested in the comments by [Ole V. V.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5772882/ole-v-v) (the comment has been deleted). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57419228/10871900) for details on that.

Both methods assume the timestamp being in microseconds since January 1st, 1970 (the UNIX-Epoch).

Comment: Yes, right you are. Its just for example. In fact its gonna be real micros.

Comment: @dan1st But how about formatting it? When I write like this: LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(dateTime), ZoneId.systemDefault()).format(dateTimeFormatter));  It still returning parse exception.

Comment: Don't use `LocalDateTime.parse` here. If you want to print it, you can use `.format`.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash I was talking about converting microseconds to milliseconds, not the other way.

Comment: If one has 5 seconds in microseconds, they'd have `5_000_000` microseconds. In order to convert that to milliseconds, one needs to divide it by 1000 so they get `5_000` milliseconds that can be used in `Instant.ofEpochMilli`. I was talking about converting milliseconds to an `Instant`. What should be wrong about that (apart from my typo)?

Comment: As I had said in my previous comment (which I deleted later because I had mentioned the wrong calculation in hurry), it's a great answer. There is no problem with division but I strongly recommend using `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(timestamp-in-mircoseconds, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS)`.