# joda DateTimeFormat local timezone formatting question

Tags: jodatime

I'm starting with an org.joda.time.DateTime and I want to output it with a timezone offset equivalent to the local time zone.  It's really for the convenience of a user looking at the time with his eyes (rather than parsing it with a proper ISO8601 parser).

```
val tz = DateTimeZone.getDefault()
val formatter = JacksonJodaDateFormat(DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ").withZone(tz))
```

What I get out is this:

```
2020-02-01T05:00:00+0000
```

What I want is this:

```
2020-02-01T00:00:00-0500
```

What it's outputting is actually correct for my time zone, but I told it .withZone(tz) and I confirmed (through the debugger) that tz is in fact America/New_York.

I'm using jodatime 2.10.2.  I've also got jackson-format-jodatime in the mix here but I tried this with jackson out of the loop and it behaves the same.

[The Documents](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withZone-org.joda.time.DateTimeZone-) say this:

```
When printing, this zone will be used in preference to the zone from the datetime that would otherwise be used.
```

The one that would otherwise be printed is UTC, but that's not what I want it to do.

Am I interpreting what the javadocs say incorrectly?

Comment: Quick clarifications: (1) `val` is not a Java keyword - is that from Lombok? (2) What version of Java are you using? (From Java 8 onwards, `java.time` is preferred over Joda-Time - but migration may not be an option for you).

Comment: It's kotlin, sorry.  I go back and forth between java and kotlin without even thinking about it nowadays.  Yep I'm using GraalVM 11 so I definitely could use java.time instead, is that really considered preferred (i.e. joda is considered obsolete) by most people now?

Comment: The good people behind Joda Time were instrumental in implementing `java.time`.  They recommend no longer using Joda Time.  See their notes [here](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) (the "Why Joda Time" section).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't object to a Java answer (perhaps your code snippet is Kotlin?), the following will format the date string as you want, and handle time zone shifts.

To keep things simple, I also did not use the Jackson library, as you mentioned.

You can obviously replace the timezone IDs below with whatever you need for your starting point - such as `"UTC"`. Or for the system default, using Joda-Time:

```
DateTimeZone defaultZone = DateTimeZone.getDefault();
```

### Joda-Time

```
//
// Using Joda-Time 2.10.2:
//

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;

...

String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ";
String dateString;

DateTime dtOne = new DateTime("2020-02-21T09:30:45.678+00:00");
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern);

DateTime dtTwo = dtOne.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York"));
dateString = fmt.print(dtTwo);   // "2020-02-21T04:30:45-0500":

DateTime dtThree = dtOne.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/Paris"));
dateString = fmt.print(dtThree); // "2020-02-21T10:30:45+0100"
```

### java.time

For Java 8 onwards, if you can use `java.time`, then `withZoneSameInstant()` shifts the date and time accordingly:

```
//
// Using java.time (Java 8 onwards):
//

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

...
String pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ";
String dateString;

DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2020-02-21T09:30:45.123");
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTimeA = localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"));

dateString = zonedDateTimeA.format(format); // "2020-02-21T09:30:45+0100"

ZonedDateTime zonedDateTimeB = zonedDateTimeA
        .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));    
dateString = zonedDateTimeB.format(format); // "2020-02-21T03:30:45-0500"
```

For the default timezone using `java.time`, it's `ZoneId.systemDefault()`.

Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437550/whats-the-difference-between-instant-and-localdatetime/32443004#32443004) is an amazing overview.

### Edit: Use `java.time` instead of Joda Time

The following was mentioned in the question's comments, but needs to be stated in this answer, also:

If you can, you absolutely should use `java.time` over Joda Time.

From the Joda Time [homepage](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

And from [Stephen Colebourne](https://blog.joda.org/2014/11/converting-from-joda-time-to-javatime.html), one of the creators of Joda Time:

> I use the phraseology that java.time is "inspired by Joda-Time", rather than an exact derivation, however many concepts will be familiar.