# How to get a Date instance with time of a day at a certain time (like 12:00:00.000) in a specific time zone?

Tags: java, datetime, localdate

for example, now it is 2020-03-16 11:23:23.121 in Vietnam, but my program is running in the USA, how to get a Date instance which is 2020-03-16 12:00:00.000 in Vietnam, which mean, I keep the year, month, day as the same, but set hour as 12, minute, second and nanosecond as 0, can LocalDateTime play a role?

Comment: can you please explain with some input and output clear example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(2020, 3, 16, 12, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh"));
```

Comment: how about the micro-second part?

Comment: @lily The last parameter before the zoneid is nanoseconds.

Comment: yes, I mean how to make all elements below hour is 0?

Comment: can LocalDateTime play a role?

Comment: @lily You put `0,0,0` just as I showed in my answer

Answer (score 2):

## `ZonedDateTime`

From java-8 you can use [ZonedDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) to get the date time from any zone

```
ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh"))
```

And the you can modify the time  to `12:00:00` using [with](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#with-java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjuster-) method. Pass the time of day as a `LocalTime` object obtained by calling [`LocalTime.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html#of(int,int)). In the new `LocalTime` object, the second and the nanosecond default to zero, so no need to pass those arguments to the factory method.

```
dateTime.with( LocalTime.of( 12 , 0 ) )  //2020-03-16T12:00+07:00[Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh]
```

Java util [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) will not store any time zone information and it just  represents a specific instant in time (which is only UTC), with millisecond precision. I will suggest to avoid using legacy `util.Date`

Comment: can LocalDateTime play a role?

Comment: For me OP requirement is not clear and for me it seems he needs to get date time from one zone and convert it into `util.Date`, `LocalDateTime` can help if he just need date and time from  Vietnam @lily

Comment: now, I want to keep year, month, day as the same, but set hour as 12, and all other parts below it, like minute, second, nanosecond as 0 in Vietnam onetime

Answer (score 0):

## No, do not use `LocalDateTime` here

> can LocalDateTime play a role?

`LocalDateTime` cannot represent a moment, as it lacks the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. So that is exactly the *wrong* classs to use here on your Question.

To represent a moment, a specific point on the timeline, use:

- `Instant` (always in UTC)
- `OffsetDateTime` (carries an offset-from-UTC, a number of hours-minutes-seconds)
- `ZonedDateTime` (carries an assigned time zone, named in `Continent/Region`)

See the correct [Answer by Deadpool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60700021/642706) showing the proper use of `ZonedDateTime` to solve your problem.

For more info, see [*What's the difference between Instant and LocalDateTime?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32437550/642706)