# Instant dates and times in Java 8 and Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, datetime

I'm using Java 8 and Spring Boot in Intellij IDEA to create a board game. For now I have a Game class and a Repository of it, as well as a SalvoApplication class.

I want to know how to pass arguments in the father class (SalvoApp) for every Game which is created show a instant of date and time.
Here is the code for Game class (date and time method instant)(I'm not sure about it, the .atzone is in red)

```
public static void of(Instant instant, ZoneId zone) {
    Date date = new Date();
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2020-03-30T12:28:00", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT);
    LocalDateTime .atZone (ZoneId.systemDefault ()). ToInstant ();
    Instant instant1 = Instant.parse("2020-03-30T12:28:00z");
}
```

And this is for SalvoApp

```
@Bean
public CommandLineRunner initData(GameRepository repository) {
    return (args) -> {
        // save a couple of games
        repository.save(new Game());
        repository.save(new Game());
        repository.save(new Game());
    };
}
```

Comment: I’m afraid it’s neither clear nor focused enough. Can you explain more clearly and precisely what your desired result is? Because I did not understand. And report what your search brought up and in what way it was insufficient? So we know more precisely how we may help you.

Comment: Your Question is not clear; rewrite to explain more. But I can say that it seems you are trying to track specific moments, and `LocalDateTime` is the wrong class for that. See [*What is the difference between LocalDateTime and Instant?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437550/ddg#32443004)

Comment: The `Z` on the end of a string input to indicate Zulu time (offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds) should be uppercase, rather than lowercase as seen in your example data. Ex: `Instant.parse( "2020-03-30T12:28:00Z" )`

Comment: Do not mix legacy date-time classes such as `Date` with the modern *java.time* classes. Use only *java.time* classes.

Comment: @BasilBourque Funnily `Instant.parse()` isn’t case sensitive, so lower case `z` works here too. I don’t know whether [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC)) accepts it, though.

Comment: @OleV.V. Hello! Thank you so much for your reply! I have to create three games. I want to create a method to calculate the instant date and time for a first game and then the date and time of two new games that will start one and two hours later respectively from the first one.
Apparently it would have to happen in the Salvo class, the precise arguments for the dates and times of these games of the Game class. Hope this can help you!

Comment: @OleV.V. this is from my notebook: Create the Sample Data
Change your CommandLineRunner in your application class to create three games, using new Game(). (I already do it)

After creating the games, but before saving them, set the dates of the second and third games to one hour and two hours later, respectively. See the Date section of the Java eBook for how to create dates from other dates.

Comment: *pass arguments in the father class* — do you want to pass the start times as arguments to `initData()`? *show a instant of date and time* — should `SalvoApp`do this, or which class should? Is *salvo* Portuguese for *save*?

Comment: @OleV.V. Regarding the `Z` being upper/lowercase, I got curious. So I skimmed [this draft](https://www.loc.gov/standards/datetime/iso-tc154-wg5_n0038_iso_wd_8601-1_2016-02-16.pdf) of ISO 8601 dated 2016-02-16. Section 4.2.4 says that expression of UTC shall be "followed immediately, without space, by the UTC designator [Z]". All their examples are uppercase `Z`, never `z`. However, section 3.4.1 Note 1 says "In date and time representations lower case characters may be used when upper case characters are not available".  So I think the spec recommends uppercase `Z` over `z` but accepts both.

Comment: @Nikita99 Provide further info as edits to your Question, not as Comments.

Comment: @OleV.V. I have to pass the start times as arguments to each new Game() but I dont know how to do that. No, is _GameClass_ that should show a instant of date and time, I have the ´creationDate´ as atributte in this class, but I dont know which method return this in Java 8. _Salvo_ is the name of the app and the name of the father class. This has no meaning in any language I think.