# Using java's Calendar.add(5,1) and repeats for many times the hours of the date goes wrong！

Tags: java

This is my programme:

```
    public class Test {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        Calendar a = Calendar.getInstance();
        a.setTime(new Date(1949-1900,0,24,0,0,0));
        Calendar b=Calendar.getInstance();
        b.setTime(new Date(1951-1900,2,24,0,0,0));
        System.out.println(a.getTime());
        while(!a.equals(b)) {
            a.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
            System.out.println(a.getTime());
        }
        System.out.println(a.getTime());
    }
}
```

The output are

```
Fri Nov 23 01:00:00 CST 5285
Sat Nov 24 01:00:00 CST 5285
Sun Nov 25 01:00:00 CST 5285
Mon Nov 26 01:00:00 CST 5285
Tue Nov 27 01:00:00 CST 5285
```

why hours goes to 1 but not 0?
And when I change the date, it may be changed back to 0.

Comment: Please use the new date time API (LocalDate, LocalDateTime,...) introduced in Java 8. The old API (Date, Calendar,...) has too many flaws. The `Date` constructor you are using is also deprecated.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. I get Mon Jan 24 00:00:00 CST 1949, Tue Jan 25 00:00:00 CST 1949, etc. up to Sat Mar 24 00:00:00 CST 1951.

Comment: Which time zone are you in? Is that CST for Cuba Standard Time, China Standard Time or something else?

Comment: ...... In my college my teachers still teach us these apis.....

Comment: Where’s the dislike button? :-) I don’t mean your question or comment, I mean teachers who teach `Calendar` and related classes 6 years after the far better replacement came out deserve to be sacked.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you still using [outdated date/time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)? The example given below is not the answer to your question but an example of modern date/time API. I would recommend you not waste time experimenting with outdated API and start using [modern date/time API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html).

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDateTime a = LocalDateTime.now();
        LocalDateTime b = LocalDateTime.now().plusHours(3);
        while (a.getHour() != b.getHour()) {
            System.out.println(a);
            a = a.plusHours(1);
        }
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-04-19T09:00:22.444642
2020-04-19T10:00:22.444642
2020-04-19T11:00:22.444642
2020-04-19T12:00:22.444642
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
GregorianCalendar                        // Terrible legacy class that should no longer be used.
.from(                                   // Convert from modern *java.time* object to legacy `Calendar` object.
    LocalDate                            // Represent a date only, without time-of-day and without time zone or offset.
    .of( 1949 , Month.JANUARY , 24 )     // Instantiate a `LocalDate` for a specific date.
    .atStartOfDay(                       // Determine the first moment of the day. Not necessarily 00:00.
        ZoneId.of( "America/Chicago" )   // Specify your desired/expected time zone.
    )                                    // Return a modern `ZonedDateTime` object. 
    .plusDays( 1 )                       // Move to the next day, accounting for any adjustments in the time-of-day because of changes to the offset for that time zone such as Daylight Saving Time (DST). 
)                                        // Return a legacy `Calendar` object, specifically a `GregorianCalendar` object.
```

## Time zone issue likely

I imagine your issue is due to time zones. A `java.util.Date` is a moment in UTC, while a `Calendar` object carries a time zone. If you do not specify a time zone, the JVM’s current default time zone is applied implicitly.

## *java.time*

But **the issue is moot**. You should not be using these terrible date-time classes. They were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Apparently you want to loop days from 1949-01-24 to 1951-03-24.

### `LocalDate`

For a date-only value, without time-of-day and without time zone, use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html). Notice the sane year numbers, no subtracting 1900.

```
LocalDate start = LocalDate.of( 1949 , Month.JANUARY , 24 ) ;
LocalDate stop = LocalDate.of( 1951 , Month.MARCH , 24 ) ;
```

Use Java streams to get a series of `LocalDate` objects.

```
Stream < LocalDate > dates = start.datesUntil( stop ) ;  // Generate a series of `LocalDate` objects.
dates.forEach( System.out::println ) ;                   // For each `LocalDate` object, call its `println` method to generate text in standard ISO 8601 format for display on the console.
```

### `ZonedDateTime`

If you meant to include the first moment of the day as a time-of-day as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people of a certain region, specify a time zone to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

Do not assume the day starts at 00:00. Some dates in some zones may start at another time such as 01:00. Let *java.time* determine the first moment by calling [`LocalDate::atStartOfDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay(java.time.ZoneId)).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtStart = start.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtStop = stop.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

Loop, adding a day at a time.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = zdtStart ;
while ( zdt.isBefore( zdtStop ) ) 
{
    System.out.println( zdt ) ;
    zdt = zdt.plusDays( 1 ) ;    // Increment to the next day, taking into account changes in the offset-from-UTC such as Daylight Saving Time (DST). 
}
```

### `LocalDateTime` cannot represent a moment

If you are trying to track moments, specific points on the timeline, then [do not use `LocalDateTime`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32437550/642706)

### `java.util.Calendar`

If you *must* use `java.util.Calendar`, to interoperate with old code or crusty instructors not yet updated to *java.time*, convert. To convert, call the new conversion methods added to the old classes.

A `ZonedDateTime` object maps to a [`GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) object, a concrete subclass of the abstract [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html).

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = zdtStart ;
while ( zdt.isBefore( zdtStop ) ) 
{
    Calendar c = GregorianCalendar.from( zdt ) ;  // Convert to obsolete terrible legacy class.
    zdt = zdt.plusDays( 1 ) ;    // Increment to the next day, taking into account changes in the offset-from-UTC such as Daylight Saving Time (DST). 
}
```