# is it possible to work with time as a String in java

Tags: java, string, time

I'm working on a java JFrame project for school. I've really been struggling to work with the java time package so I was wondering if it would be possible to work with time in a string variable.

My program s automating the process of making a study timetable. A user will enter the start and end time of any activities that they have. I then take this time and manipulate it into a string `hh: mm` (`e.g:` `4 PM` would be `16:00`).

```
        String finalTime="";
        if (dropBox.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("PM")) {
            int time = Integer.parseInt((txt.getText().substring(0,2)));
            time = time + 12;
            finalTime =  Integer.toString(time) + txt.getText().substring(2, 5);
        }
        else {
            finalTime = txt.getText();
        }
        return finalTime;
```

After their activities are stored in my database, I ask them to input the date for each of their exams. Using these dates I make different 'study slots' for each exam (String subject, java.sql.Date date, String startTime, String endTime).

The first study slot is exactly three weeks before the exam (or if they create it when there is less time their first study slot is on the day they make the timetable) and the last one is one day before the exam.

I'm still trying to work out how to do the rest of them but I will most probably assign each exam a specific number of study slots and then randomize which slot goes when.

What I was planning on doing was avoiding assigning study slots at the same time as the user has entered that they have activities. However, I cannot work out how to do this whether I'm storing time as a String or using the `java.time` package. Any assistance would really be appreciated.

If I have not provided enough information or code please let me know, I am still very new to this!

Comment: @user don't recommend `java.util.Date` anymore. It's 2020. As for working with time values as Strings, that's a bad idea. The whole idea of the `java.time` classes is to make date handling easy to do correctly. If you do it yourself with Strings, you'll get it wrong (that's guaranteed).

Comment: My bad. Just see the time package (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) then

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `java.sql.Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` for the date and `LocalTime` for the times of day. Both are from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI, calendaring is not an easy task for new programmer. The job is more tricky and complicated than you might intuit. For one thing, you will need to get very clear on the difference between (a) a date-with-time and (b) a moment, as discussed on [*What's the difference between Instant and LocalDateTime?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32437550/642706).

---

Never use `java.util.Date`. Use only the modern classes found in the *java.time* package.

For a time-of-day, use [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html).

```
LocalTime start = LocalTime.of( 16 , 0 ) ;
```

Display to user by automatically localizing.

```
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;  // Or `Locale.US`, `Locale.UK` or such.
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime( FormatStyle.MEDIUM ).withLocale( locale ) ;
String output = start.format( f ) ;
```

Specify the length of time for the exam slot as a [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html).

```
Duration duration = Duration.ofHours( 1 ) ;
```

Usually best for a scheduling app to store the start and the duration, but not the end. The end can always be calculated.

Calculate the ending time. Adding the duration to a `LocalTime` object generates a new and separate `LocalTime` object rather than alter the original ([immutable objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object)).

```
LocalTime end = start.plus( duration ) ;
```

Beware: Adding a span of time to a `LocalTime` ignores the issue of time zone anomalies such as [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time). Better to add the duration to the `ZonedDateTime` object seen below.

For date, use [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html).

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2020 , Month.MARCH , 23 ) ;
```

Move back in time three weeks by using the [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Period.html) class.

```
Period period = Period.ofWeeks( 3 ) ;
LocalDate examDate = ld.minus( period ) ; // 3 weeks prior.
```

Combine the date and time-of-day into a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html).

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of( examDate , start ) ;
```

To determine a moment, a specific point on the timeline, provide the context of a time zone. You get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtStart = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
```

Get the ending time.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtEnd = zdtStart.plus( duration ) ;  // Automatically accounts for anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST).
```

To see that moment in UTC, extract an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html).

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

As for database storage, some databases such as [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) and [H2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)) have good support for date-time data types. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) that complies with [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) 4.2 or later to exchange *java.time* objects via the `setObject`/`getObject` methods.

Unfortunately, [JDBC 4.2](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221) requires support for [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) but not the more commonly used `Instant` and `ZonedDateTime` types. No problem really, as we can easily convert back-and-forth.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Tip: For this kind of work you may want to add the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project to access the [*Interval*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html) and/or [`LocalDateRange`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/LocalDateRange.html) classes. These represent a span-of-time tied to the timeline, as a pair of `Instant` objects or `LocalDate` objects respectively.

I have been brief here. All this has been covered many many times already on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKgbN.png

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).