# Why is this converted Jackson time different to expected Unix time?

Tags: java, date, jackson-databind

**Edit**: It turns out the problem is not about Jackson, but about time adjustment in Thailand on 1 April 1920.

How does com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper works? I thought it used Unix timestamp.

I tried converting a java.util.Date with mapper.writeValueAsString().

When I convert the string back to Date with mapper.readerFor(Date.class).readValue(), the result is correct.

However, when I trying removing the last 3 digits and and put the same string into some converter websites, the result is off for some minutes and seconds.

Please see the code below.

```java
Date wayBack = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("1900-01-31");
System.out.println(wayBack); // Wed Jan 31 00:00:00 ICT 1900
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(wayBack)); // -2206420924000
Date deserialised = mapper.readerFor(Date.class).readValue(mapper.writeValueAsString(wayBack));
System.out.println(deserialised); // Wed Jan 31 00:00:00 ICT 1900
```

Below is a screenshot from http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm

[image: unix time converter]

Please note that 7-hour off is expected because of my timezone but I don't understand the 17:56 minutes different.

Comment: See [this link](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/thailand?year=1920) for a specific reference to the 17 minutes & 56 seconds change. I wrote an answer, but it was downvoted. Perhaps this will be of some help, instead.

Comment: I can't even see you answer but I think it makes sense. 17 mins and 56 seconds can't be coincidence. How come it's downvoted? Can you write a new answer with more details or I might do it after some more research.

Comment: @andrewjames Please undelete your answer and explain why a timezone change that occurred in 1920 is applying retroactively to a date in 1900.

Comment: I have updated and undeleted my answer. @sotiriosdelimanolis - thank you for your comment. I can't explain your retroactive point - I don't see where any retroactive application of the 1920 change is taking place. But my original question was wrong to emphasize that 1920 point in the way it did - I think it's not a direct answer to the question - it's a background point, at best, perhaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** - *Here is my attempt to provide a better answer than my first one.*

**Background**

Before looking at the code in the question, some background notes:

The epoch value (in seconds) at midnight 31st Jan 1900 in Bangkok is -2206420924:

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("1900-01-31T00:00:00");
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of("Asia/Bangkok");
ZonedDateTime ict_1 = ZonedDateTime.of(localDateTime, z);
System.out.println("Epoch seconds: " + ict_1.toEpochSecond());
System.out.println("ICT datetime : " + ict_1);
```

The above prints this:

```
Epoch seconds: -2206420924
ICT datetime : 1900-01-31T00:00+06:42:04[Asia/Bangkok]
```

The epoch value (in seconds) for UTC midnight on the same date is -1570060800:

```
ZonedDateTime utcDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("1900-01-31T00:00:00Z");
System.out.println("Epoch seconds: " + utcDateTime.toEpochSecond());
System.out.println("UTC datetime : " + utcDateTime);
```

The above prints this:

```
Epoch seconds: -2206396800
UTC datetime : 1900-01-31T00:00Z
```

The time at midnight in Bangkok on 31st January 1900 was 24,124 seconds further into the past than the time at midnight in Greenwich, UK (the prime meridian - or UTC).

That is to say, on that date Bangkok was 6 hours, 42 minutes and 4 seconds ahead of UTC time (or GMT as I believe it was then called - as UTC had not been established at that time).

**The Specific Code in the Question**

First, I changed my default time zone to match the one used in the question:

```
System.setProperty("user.timezone", "Asia/Bangkok");
```

The below line from the question does the following:

(1) The `SimpleDateFormat` constructor, in which the date format string does not specify a locale, uses the default locale.

(2) Then the `parse()` method creates the Date object:

```
Date wayBack = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("1900-01-31");
```

At this point we can check the date object:

```
System.out.println(wayBack);
System.out.println(wayBack.getTime());
```

This prints the following:

```
Wed Jan 31 00:00:00 ICT 1900
-2206420924000 // epoch milliseconds
```

This matches what we saw earlier, in the background section.

When you use an online tool such as the one mentioned in the question, you will see the above milliseconds value reported as the following GMT (UTC) datetime:

```
GMT: Tuesday, January 30, 1900 5:17:56 PM
```

For the above output I used [this tool](https://www.epochconverter.com/).

Again, this is what we expect - when it's midnight in Bangkok, it's still the afternoon of the day before in Greenwich, UK.

The remainder of the code (including the Jackson object mapper transformations) are all subject to this initial set-up of your `Date` object.

For the question: "*How does com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper works? I thought it used Unix timestamp.*" It shows the same behavior as the core Java date object. I believe your assumption is correct.

**Regarding the Unusual Offset**

Regarding the ICT offset of `+06:42:04` shown above:

On April 1st 1920, an adjustment was made to the local ICT (Indochina Time), to align it with UTC time (with an offset of +7 hours, as you note). The local clocks were *set forward* by 17 minutes and 56 seconds, to round up the UTC (GMT) offset to 7 hours.

See [this link](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/thailand?year=1920) for a specific reference to the 17 minutes & 56 seconds change.

This is why you will not see that unusual offset from April 1920 onwards.

**Further Links**

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32443004/12567365) regarding the newer `java.time` classes which should be used instead of `java.util.Date`.

See this [question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result) for a related deep-dive into the topic of historic time zone adjustments.

Comment: Your 4th code block shows the output of 1920. Otherwise very good answer. Thank you.

Comment: @Wit - Thank you for the feedback, it is much appreciated. I corrected my copy/paste error.