# How to compare two dates in Java and then compare the result vs another date?

Tags: java

Noob here! First I am trying to compare `dateOne` and `dateTwo` with each other, then which ever that has the most recent date `(> 0)` take it and compare that versus the `cutOffDate`.

If its after `cutOffDate`, set that to be `FinalDate`, else set `cutOffDate` to be `FinalDate`. How can I achieve this?

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track here, I am getting the following error with `dateOne.compareTo(dateTwo)`:

> The method compareTo(String) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (Date)

```
public DateServiceImpl process(final DateServiceImpl item) throws Exception {

    final Date dateOne = item.getDateOne();
    final Date dateTwo = item.getDateTwo();

    final BigDecimal amountOne= item.getAmountOne();
    final BigDecimal amountTwo= item.getAmountTwo();

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    String cutOffDate = "01/01/2020";

    Date cDate = sdf.parse(cutOffDate);
    if ((amountOne.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) > 0) && (amountTwo.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) > 0)){
        if (dateOne.compareTo(dateTwo) <= 0) {
             item.setFinalDate(cDate);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not an answer, but... you should avoid the older `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes wherever possible, and instead use the newer `java.time` classes, such as `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion/4216767#4216767) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437550/whats-the-difference-between-instant-and-localdatetime) for some background.

Comment: *it seems to have a problem with `dateOne.compareTo(dateTwo)`*... please clarify what "seems to have a problem" means exactly. If an error, what is the error. If unexpected result, what was the actual result and the expected result?

Comment: @Bohemian Yes, error message: "The method compareTo(String) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (Date)"

Comment: @Vladik better check your code in the question, because it cannot throw that error. is it possible your code is actually comparing `cutOffDate` with a date?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: When posting here on Stack Overflow, delete all extraneous code from your Question. The parts using `BigDecimal` are irrelevant to this topic and should have been excised.

Comment: `java.util.Date` or `java.sql.Date`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the right track. You just need another comparison and you should be good.

```
if (dateOne.compareTo(dateTwo) > 0) {
    if (dateOne.compareTo(cDate) > 0) {
        item.setFinalDate(dateOne);
    } else {
        item.setFinalDate(cDate);
    }
} else {
    if (dateTwo.compareTo(cDate) > 0) {
        item.setFinalDate(dateTwo);
    } else {
        item.setFinalDate(cDate);
    }
}
```

You needed to check each case of which order the dates come in (check if `dateOne` comes before `dateTwo` and check if `dateOne` comes after `dateTwo`). Then, for each of those checks, you have to check whether the most recent date comes before or after the cutoff date.

Answer (score 5):

### LocalDate from java.time and Collections.max()

Do use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date work. First, java.time allows to declare the formatter once and for all:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

I understand that the final date should be the latest of `dateOne`, `dateTwo` and the cut-off date. Given that `DateServiceImpl` uses `LocalDate` instead of `Date`, the logic can be simplified:

```
    LocalDate dateOne = item.getDateOne();
    LocalDate dateTwo = item.getDateTwo();

    String cutOffDate = "01/01/2020";

    LocalDate cDate = LocalDate.parse(cutOffDate, DATE_FORMATTER);

    LocalDate finalDate = Collections.max(Arrays.asList(dateOne, dateTwo, cDate));

    item.setFinalDate(finalDate);
```

I have left out the `final` declarations and the amount logic since they weren’t relevant to the question asked; you can put those back in yourself.

A `LocalDate` is a date without time of day. I thought that this was what you needed, please check yourself.

Edit: as Basil Bourque suggests in a comment, if using Java 9 or later, you will probably prefer `List.of()` over `Arrays.asList()`:

```
    LocalDate finalDate = Collections.max(List.of(dateOne, dateTwo, cDate));
```

For situations where this is not enough `LocalDate` also has methods `isBefore` and `isAfter` for comparisons.

### Collections.max() works with Date too

If you cannot afford to upgrade `DateServiceImpl` to java.time just now, you may use `Collections.max()` on three old-fashioned `Date` objects in the same way.

`Collections.max()` also comes in an overloaded version that takes `Comparator` as its second argument. Since both `LocalDate` and `Date` implement `Comparable` we don’t need that here.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Documentation of `Collections.max()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection))

Comment: Thanks for teaching me `Collections.max`. For those using Java 9 and later, using [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#of(E,E,E)) might be a tad easier to read than `Arrays.asList`: `LocalDate finalDate = Collections.max( List.of( dateOne , dateTwo , cDate ) );`. But same effect either way.