# Convert time in long format from UTC to EST

Tags: java, zoneddatetime

Looking for ideas to convert time in long (millis) from UTC to EST
Tried in the below manner and did not work. I am seeing epcohET is same as input parameter.

```
long time = 1693932120000
Instant dateTime = Instant.ofEpochMilli(time);
ZoneId usET = ServerTimeZone.TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York").toZoneId();
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(dateTime, usET);
long epochET = zdt.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
```

Comment: Instants will be the same regardless of Zones, that's what they mean. It's an instant point on the global (universal) time-line. The number of seconds and nanos since a point in time. It is the same across the whole planet.
The thing that changes is OffsetDateTime / ZonedDateTime as that's the time you'd observe at a specific instant while being on different places on Earth.
In other words, the Instant never changes and is the same everywhere. If you want time specific for a place, use Offset/Zoned*.

Comment: Epoch time in millis is the number of millis from January 1, 1970 at Greenwich. So, the time zone doesn't matter, and epochET should be the same as the input.

Comment: clues here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62879021/zoneddatetime-toinstant-toepochmilli-losing-zone-data

Comment: Thank you. So is there any other way to get convert long time from UTC to ET (without using ZonedDateTime)?

Comment: @Rohan There's no conversion, because they have the same value. It's the same regardless of what time zone you're in, because the begginning of the epoch is based on UTC, not the local time zone.

Comment: “EST” and “ET” are not real time zones. Real time zones have a name in format of `Continent/Region` such as `America/New_York` and `America/Montreal`.

Answer (score 3):

[`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) represents just a moment in time and is independent of the timezone.

You can use [`Instant#atZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#atZone-java.time.ZoneId-) to get the desired result.

**Demo:**

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long timestamp = 1693932120000L;
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(timestamp);
        ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
        System.out.println(zdt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2023-09-05T12:42-04:00[America/New_York]
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/ELynbL)

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**

Comment: I am expecting output to be in long as well. But my understanding is long will be same as input and won't change.

Comment: @Rohan That's correct. The `long` timestamp is independent of the timezone. The documentation and tutorial I have linked in my answer will be very helpful to you if you want to understand date-time-related concepts.

Answer (score 1):

> So is there any other way to get convert long time from UTC to ET (without using ZonedDateTime)?

If you're talking about long from one `TZ` to long in another, no.  Instants and epochs don't have time zones (although `Instant` is treated as `Zulu` for adjustment purposes).

If you just want to get a time object and don't care about `timezone` information and just want `long milli` adjusted for some `timezone` in a `LocalDateTime` this will work.  If you want `timezones` to be included in the output, simply replace the calls using `LocalDateTime` with `ZonedDateTime` Try it like this but use your specific Zones.  Note that if you print out an `Instant` it defaults to `Zulu` or `UTC`.  So any `TZ` adjustment will be made from that point.

```
Long millis = 1694009579442L;
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(millis);


LocalDateTime ldt1 = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant,
        ZoneId.of("US/Eastern"));
LocalDateTime ldt2 = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant,
        ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"));
System.out.println(ldt1);
System.out.println(ldt2);
```

prints

```
2023-09-06T10:12:59.442
2023-09-06T16:12:59.442
```