# How to get current time for timezone

Tags: java

I have UTC time offsets for specific operations stored like this: (this one is for UTC+2)

```
double utc = 2.0;
```

How can I get current time for that timezone using this double time offset in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to convert the `double` value to a `ZoneOffset`:

```java
double utc = 2.0;

ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds((int) (utc * 3600));
```

You can then get the current time:

```java
OffsetDateTime now = Instant.now().atOffset(offset);
```

*Sample Output*

```
2020-09-22T21:16:42.816236600+02:00
```

Answer (score 5):

You may combine

- [`ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#ofTotalSeconds(int)) to get the offset zone from the hour offset
- [`Instant.atOffset`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html#atOffset(java.time.ZoneOffset)) to get the `OffsetDatetime` from current `Instant` and the `ZoneOffset`

```
OffsetDateTime odt = Instant.now().atOffset(ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds((int) (2.0*3600)));
```

---

#### [`Code Demo`](https://repl.it/repls/WelloffEducatedNewsaggregator)

Comment: Better to use `Instant.now().atOffset(...)`. Less waste. Clearer intent.

Comment: While the answer is useful enough not to be down-voted, it doesn't actually answer the question, which was *"How can I get current time for that timezone **using this `double`** time offset in Java?"*

Comment: @Andreas the cast from double to int ? Because `ZoneOffset.ofHours(2)` seems nicer than `ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds(3600 * 2)`

Comment: `double india = 5.5;` Ehhh.... No, cast to `int` will not do. Or how about `double offset = 1.3255555555555556;`, aka `1:19:32`, used by `Europe/Amsterdam` 1916-1937?

Answer (score 1):

**Two other alternatives:**

Using:

```
double utc = 2.0;
```

Alternative 1:

```
ZonedDateTime nowAlt1 = Instant.now().atZone(ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds((int) utc * 3600));
```

Alternative 2:

```
 ZonedDateTime nowAlt2 = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.now(), ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds((int) utc * 3600));
```

Alternative 1 and 2 in context:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double utc = 2.0;
    ZonedDateTime nowAlt1 = Instant.now().atZone(ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds((int) utc * 3600));
    ZonedDateTime nowAlt2 = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.now(), ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds((int) utc * 3600));

    System.out.println("nowAlt1: " + nowAlt1);
    System.out.println("nowAlt2: " + nowAlt2);
}
```

Output:

```
nowAlt1: 2020-09-22T23:15:00.254912800+02:00
nowAlt2: 2020-09-22T23:15:00.253915600+02:00
```

Read more about java.time here, will give you an idea when to use the different types of java.time:
[What's the difference between Instant and LocalDateTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437550/whats-the-difference-between-instant-and-localdatetime)