# java zoneddatetime toEpochSecond without converting to local time

Tags: java, zoneddatetime

I have a dataset that is in EST time without any daylight saving.
Each datetime is read from string and a zonedDatetime is created using

```
ZonedDateTime java.time.ZonedDateTime.of(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth, int hour, int minute, int second, int nanoOfSecond, ZoneId zone)
```

with a ZoneId.of("America/New_York");

I need to convert these to an epoch second but the built in toEpochSecond method converts to my local time which is BST with day light saving. As a result the timestamps are four to five hours off depending on time of year. Is there a way to get a unix timestamp that does not take into account any local time so the timestamp matches the datetime in the original string?

Comment: What makes you think that `toEpochSecond` converts to BST?  It converts to a timezoneless value.  It's probable that whatever you're using to _check the value_ of `toEpochSecond` is inserting your local timezone.

Comment: from javadoc>Converts this date-time to the number of seconds from the epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.
This uses the local date-time and offset to calculate the epoch-second value, which is the number of elapsed seconds from 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. Instants on the time-line after the epoch are positive, earlier are negative.    here is the actual code of toEpochSecond>   default long toEpochSecond() {
        long epochDay = toLocalDate().toEpochDay();
        long secs = epochDay * 86400 + toLocalTime().toSecondOfDay();
        secs -= getOffset().getTotalSeconds();
        return secs;
 }

Comment: Yes, and?  It uses the zone from the `ZonedDateTime`, "America/New_York", which is exactly the right behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To convert ZonedDateTime to Unix epoch time stamp**

Convert first to java.time.Instant and then set zone offset to UTC, before converting it to epoch seconds, see below:

```
zonedDateTime.toInstant().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochSecond();
```

Note: The variable zonedDateTime is of type java.time.ZonedDateTime and can be in any time zone before converting it to "Unix epoch time stamp" in seconds.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I was looking for

Comment: Great! If you want to read more about java.time, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437550/whats-the-difference-between-instant-and-localdatetime. The answer with 940+ votes. This reading has helped me in the passed, considering java.time.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to convert these to an epoch second but the built in
> toEpochSecond method converts to my local time which is BST with day
> light saving. As a result the timestamps are four to five hours off
> depending on time of year.

You must be doing something fundamentally wrong. Check the output of the following code and you will find that there is no difference.

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Formatter ignoring nanoseconds
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                        .appendPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX")
                                        .optionalStart()
                                        .appendLiteral('[')
                                        .parseCaseSensitive()
                                        .appendZoneRegionId()
                                        .appendLiteral(']')
                                        .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);

        // The given time-zone
        ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");

        ZonedDateTime zdtNow = ZonedDateTime.now(zone);
        System.out.println(zdtNow.format(formatter));

        // Epoch seconds from ZonedDateTime
        long epochSecond = zdtNow.toEpochSecond();
        System.out.println(epochSecond);

        // ZonedDateTime from epoch seconds
        ZonedDateTime zdtFromEpochSeconds = Instant.ofEpochSecond(epochSecond).atZone(zone);
        System.out.println(zdtFromEpochSeconds.format(formatter));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-09-28T17:31:23-04:00[America/New_York]
1601328683
2020-09-28T17:31:23-04:00[America/New_York]
```