# How to use abstraction with classes LocalDate and LocalDateTime?

Tags: java, dry

I have the following code:

```
LocalDate date;
LocalDate minDate;

//constructor...

if(date.isBefore(minDate)){
   throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

and similar with LocalDateTime:

```
LocalDateTime date;
LocalDateTime minDate;

//constructor...

if(date.isBefore(minDate)){
   throw new RuntimeException();
}
```

Can I use some interface or abstract class thanks to which I wouldn't have to write the same code twice? I can't find such an interface.
As you can see I am using only 'isBefore' and 'isAfter' methods.

Comment: Please add a little more context! Where are you getting the dates and times from?

Comment: How about [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are more general types shared by these classes, such as `Temporal`.  But they are *not* meant to be used by app developers generally.

And those more general types do not share the `isBefore`/`isAfter` methods.

I think you are being fooled by the coincidentally named methods into thinking that these date-time classes are mere variations of each other. But they are not. A `LocalDate` is really a different animal than `LocalDateTime`. And so, in reference to your DRY tag, you actually are not repeating yourself here. Trying to abstract away the distinction between a date-only and a date-with-time is not valid.

In contrast, notice how `LocalDate` implements the more general interface [`ChronoLocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/chrono/ChronoLocalDate.html), where the `isBefore`/`isAfter` methods come from. That interface is shared among five classes within Java (HijrahDate, JapaneseDate, LocalDate, MinguoDate, ThaiBuddhistDate) and even more classes in the *ThreeTen-Extra* project. Those classes are the same kind of animal, various ways to identify each date on a calendar. For these classes abstracting all these classes as a `ChronoLocalDate` is logically appropriate, and (apparently) useful to the *java.time* framework.

Note that I am not suggesting the use of `ChronoLocalDate` in your app. The Javadoc clearly warns us against such usage as a general rule. I’m merely trying to show that date-only classes are “kind of the same” while date-only and date-with-time classes are not.

Comment: I agree completely. The two snippets in the question indeed have a similarity, but look more similar than they are because the `LocalDateTime` is misnamed `date`. It should be `dateTime`. Had the fields had type `Integer` and the check been `integer < minInteger`, the similarity would have remained. Trying to abstract such similarity away has no gain, only needless complication.

Answer (score -1):

Instant.
Both LocalDate and LocalDateTime can be converted to Instant.

Comment: Not true at all. An `Instant` represents a moment, a specific point on the timeline. Neither `LocalDate` nor `LocalDateTime` represent a moment. To get to a moment you would have to add information, a time-of-day and/or time zone, which is not already present.

Comment: It is not working fine because I need to parse everytime

Comment: That is indeed a wrong answer. Sorry about that. And i saw your answer about the question "difference between Instant and LocalDateTime". I got a lot ,thanks  Basil Bourque.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437550/whats-the-difference-between-instant-and-localdatetime/32443004#32443004