# How to pass StringBinding and ReadOnlyProperty as generic arguments?

Tags: java, generics, javafx

I have two methods in my JavaFX-code for creating TextFields with Bindings. I have to bind `ReadOnlyProperty` or `StringBinding`. So I created two methods with different method signatures but with the same code in the block.

How can I simplify my code (with generics?) to handle all the different Properties (String, Long, Object etc.)?

```
createTextField(knkFile.idProperty().asString(), 1, 0); // ReadOnlyIntegerProperty
createTextField(knkFile.dateProperty().asString(), 1, 1); // ReadOnlyObjectProperty
createTextField(knkFile.fileNameProperty(), 1, 2); // ReadOnlyStringProperty
createTextField(knkFile.lastModifiedProperty().asString(), 1, 5); // ReadOnlyLongProperty
```

```
private void createTextField(ReadOnlyProperty property, int column, int row) {
    TextField textField = new TextField();
    textField.textProperty().bind(property);
    this.add(textField, column, row); // add to GridPane
}

private void createTextField(StringBinding binding, int column, int row) {
    TextField textField = new TextField();
    textField.textProperty().bind(binding);
    this.add(textField, column, row);
}
```

## Edit: own answer (deprecated - see accepted answer)

I just saw that `StringBinding` and `ReadOnlyProperty` implement `ObservableValue`. So I only need this method now:

```
private void createTextField(ObservableValue property, int column, int row) {
    TextField textField = new TextField();
    textField.textProperty().bind(property);
    this.add(textField, column, row);
}
```

Comment: Don’t edit the question to add an answer. [Add an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to add an answer.

Comment: Don’t use raw types.

Comment: @jewelsea: Thanks, but was not possible.

Comment: @James_D Ok, thanks. I will read about that to understand what, why, how.

Comment: @kanka.dev You have sufficient reputation to answer your own question.

Comment: @James_D I tried multiple times. I can't answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution: Use `StringExpression`**

All of the values passed to your `createTextField` methods are StringExpressions, so you can create a single method that takes a [StringExpression](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.base/javafx/beans/binding/StringExpression.html) as a parameter.

You can write your example method like this:

```
private void createTextField(
        StringExpression property,
        int column,
        int row
) {
    TextField textField = new TextField();
    textField.textProperty().bind(property);
    form.add(textField, column, row);
}
```

Using a `StringExpression` is preferable to using an `ObservableValue` as defined in your updated question.

**Explanation**

A text field must be bound to an ObservableValue which is a string (type `ObservableValue<? extends String>`).

If you don't use generics in the type specification for your parameter and just use a raw type (without the part including `<>`), then you lose type safety, so compile-time type checks are not made.  For example, the compiler would allow you to pass an Integer-based rather than String-based ObservableValue into the method.  If you did that, on execution, you would get a runtime error due to a type mismatch because an Integer cannot be directly treated as a String.

A `StringExpression` implements `ObservableValue<String>`, so that means that a text field can bind to it directly and type safety at compile time is retained.

**Executable example**

[image: screenshot]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.StringExpression;
import javafx.beans.property.*;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.time.Instant;

public class BindSample extends Application {
    private final FileModel fileModel = new FileModel(
            1, Instant.now(), "test.txt", Instant.now().toEpochMilli()
    );

    private final GridPane form = new GridPane();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        form.setHgap(5);
        form.setVgap(5);
        form.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        form.addColumn(0,
                new Label("Id"),
                new Label("Date"),
                new Label("FileName"),
                new Label(),
                new Label(),
                new Label("Last Modified")
        );

        createTextField(fileModel.idProperty().asString(), 1, 0); // ReadOnlyIntegerProperty
        createTextField(fileModel.dateProperty().asString(), 1, 1); // ReadOnlyObjectProperty
        createTextField(fileModel.fileNameProperty(), 1, 2); // ReadOnlyStringProperty
        createTextField(fileModel.lastModifiedProperty().asString(), 1, 5); // ReadOnlyLongProperty

        stage.setScene(new Scene(form));
        stage.show();
    }

    private void createTextField(
            StringExpression property,
            int column,
            int row
    ) {
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.textProperty().bind(property);
        form.add(textField, column, row);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    private static class FileModel {
        private final ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper id;
        private final ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<Instant> date;
        private final ReadOnlyStringWrapper fileName;
        private final ReadOnlyLongWrapper lastModified;

        public FileModel(int id, Instant date, String fileName, long lastModified) {
            this.id = new ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper(id);
            this.date = new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(date);
            this.fileName = new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(fileName);
            this.lastModified = new ReadOnlyLongWrapper(lastModified);
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id.get();
        }

        public ReadOnlyIntegerProperty idProperty() {
            return id.getReadOnlyProperty();
        }

        public Instant getDate() {
            return date.get();
        }

        public ReadOnlyObjectProperty<Instant> dateProperty() {
            return date.getReadOnlyProperty();
        }

        public String getFileName() {
            return fileName.get();
        }

        public ReadOnlyStringProperty fileNameProperty() {
            return fileName.getReadOnlyProperty();
        }

        public long getLastModified() {
            return lastModified.get();
        }

        public ReadOnlyLongProperty lastModifiedProperty() {
            return lastModified.getReadOnlyProperty();
        }
    }
}
```

*Minor implementation notes*

1. The example uses ReadOnlyPropertys when demonstrating the binding to match your question sample code.  But for this simple example, if the model object were immutable, then a Record without Bindings could be used instead.  This can simplify the logic if you know the data never changes.
2. In the example, I use an `Instant` to represent a date as a precise moment in time, but you could use a `ZonedDateTime` for better date representation (or `LocalDateTime` or `LocalDate` if the ambiguity was OK), see [Java date representations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32443004/1155209) if you want to understand this.

Comment: hmm .. wondering why you over-specify the parameter? ObservableValue<String> should suffice, why narrow it to StringExpression?

Comment: @kleopatra because I like StringExpression :-). I like the name better and I like the additional functionality it provides, so I would prefer to use it.  But, yes, `ObservableValue<String>` would also work fine and allow a wider variety of acceptable inputs if that were more desirable or required.

Comment: thanks for explanation - yeah, we all have personal preferences :)