# Is it bad practice to use LocalDateTime for Postgres timestamps on a UTC machine as an alternative for Instant?

Tags: java, java-time, localdatetime, java.time.instant

First of all I'm aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437550/whats-the-difference-between-instant-and-localdatetime) excellent answer on the difference between `Instant` and `LocalDateTime` in Java. Both have nano-second precision but the value of `LocalDateTime.now()` depends on the machine timezone.

I save time in Postgres database using [timestamp](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) type which saves both date and time (no time zone). I'm wondering if it's OK to de/serialize time objects using `LocalDateTime` under the condition that the machine which hosts the database and the production server are set to UTC. As far as I see under this condition there's no difference between the classes at least no practical difference, both will return the number of nanoseconds since Unix epoch. The advantage of using `LocalDateTime` is that I can immediately use time methods like `getYear()`, `getDayOfMonth()` which are not available for `Instant`.

Comment: `LocalDateTime` does _not_ have a time zone (the question your linked mentions that). `ZonedDateTime` has time zone information.

Comment: Here is the first line from [Javadoc for LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html): _"A date-time without a time-zone in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such as 2007-12-03T10:15:30."_

Comment: It’s a good question but opinion-based. For my part I wouldn’t be too happy about the setup you envision. Someone happening to set a different time zone somewhere can easily cause everything to break. Also someone reading your code will need to know that times are in UTC; it won’t be stated in the code itself, which could cause confusion. You are correct, in theory you will be able to get the correct results.