# Should I use Instant or DateTime or LocalDateTime in Java entities?

Tags: java, spring-boot, date, spring-data-jpa, timestamp

In my Java (with Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA) applications, I generally use Instant. On the other hand, I would like to use the most proper data type for time values.

Could you please clarify me about these issues? What data type should I prefer for keeping date and time when:

**1.** To keep time precisely as timestamp (I am not sure if Instant is the best option)?

**2.** For normal cases when I just need date and time (as far as I know, the old library was obsolete, but not sure which library should I use).

I also consider the TimeZone, but not sure if using LocalDateTime with UTC solves my problem.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at the discussions in [What's the difference between Instant and LocalDateTime?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32437550/12567365) The answers include overviews of the concepts, Java code examples, and guidance on usage. That may help.

Comment: "the old library" — what library?

Comment: "DateTime" — What class is that? No such class bundled with Java.

Comment: " I would like to use the most proper data type" — for what purpose? Determining a proper choice means fitting some requirements or parameters dictated by your purpose/goal.

Comment: "For normal cases" — What is a "normal case" *exactly*?

Comment: "To keep time precisely as timestamp" — What do you mean by "precisely"? What do you mean by "timestamp"?

Comment: @BasilBourque "DateTime" is "joda datetime"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's assume we need to cover the full span of date and time concerns. If there is a certain concern you don't have, that either collapses various types into 'well then they are interchangible' or simply means you don't need to use a certain part of the API. The point is, you need to understand what these types *represent*, and once you know that, you know which one to apply. Because *even if* various different `java.time` types all *technically* do what you want, code is more flexible and a lot simpler to read if the types you use represent the things you want them to. For the same reason `String[] student = new String[] {"Joe McPringle", "56"};` is perhaps mechanically a way to represent a student's name and age, but things are just a lot simpler if you write a `class Student { String name; int age; }` and use that instead.

### Local alarm clock

Imagine you want to wake up at 07:00 in the morning. Not because you have an appointment, you just like to be a fairly early riser.

So you set your alarm for 07:00 in the morning, go to sleep, and your alarm promptly goes off at 7. So far, so good. However, you then hop in a plane and fly from Amsterdam to New York. (it is 6 hours earlier in new york). You then go to sleep again. Should the alarm go off at 01:00 at night, or at 07:00 in the morning?

Both answers are correct. The question is, how do you 'store' that alarm, and to answer that question, you need to figure out what the alarm is attempting to represent.

If the intent is '07:00, whereever I might be at the time the alarm is supposed to go off', the correct data storage mechanism is `java.time.LocalDateTime`, which stores time in human terms (years, months, days, hours, minutes, and seconds) and not in computery terms (we'll get there later), and does not include a time zone at all. If the alarm is supposed to go off every day, then you don't want that either, as LDT stores *date* and *time*, hence the name, you'd use `LocalTime` instead.

That's because you wanted to store the concept of 'the alarm should go off at 7 o'clock' and **nothing more than that**. You had no intention of saying: "The alarm should go off when people in Amsterdam would agree it is currently 07:00", nor did you have the intent of saying: "When the universe arrives at this exact moment in time, sound the alarm". You had the intent of saying: "When it is 07:00 where-ever you are now, sound the alarm", so store *that*, which is a `LocalTime`.

The same principle applies to `LocalDate`: It stores a year/month/day tuple with no notion of *where*.

This does draw some perhaps wonky conclusions: Given a `LocalDateTime` object, it is **not possible** to ask how long it'll take until that LDT arrives. It is also not possible for any given moment in time to be compared to an LDT, because these things are apples and oranges. The notion 'Feb 18th, 2023, 7 in the morning on the dot' isn't a singular time. After all, in New York that 'moment' occurs a full 6 *hours* earlier than it would in Amsterdam. You can only compare 2 LocalDateTimes.

Instead, you would have to first 'place' your LDT somewhere, by converting it to one of the other types (ZonedDateTime or even Instant) by asking the java.time API: Okay, I want this particular LDT in a certain time zone.

Hence, if you are writing your alarm app, you would have to take the stored alarm (a `LocalTime` object), convert it to an Instant (which is what the nature of 'what time is it now, i.e. `System.currentTimeMillis()`' works on), by saying: That LocalTime, on the current day in the current local timezone, as an instant, and THEN comparing those two results.

### Human appointments

Imagine that, just before jetting off to New York, you made an appointment at your local (in Amsterdam) barber. Their agenda was kinda busy so the appointment was set for June 20th, 2025, at 11:00.

If you stay in New York for a few years, the correct time for your calendar to remind you that you have an appointment with your barber's in an hour is certainly **not** at 10:00 on june 20th 2025 in New York. You'd have missed the appointment by then. Instead, your phone should chirp at you that you have an hour left to get to your barber's (a bit tricky, from New York, sure) at 04:00 in the middle of the night.

It sure sounds like we can say that the barber's appointment is a specific instant in time. However, **this is not correct**. The EU has already adopted legislation, agreed upon by all member states, that all EU countries shall abolish daylight savings time. However, this law does not provide a deadline, and crucially, does not provide a time zone that each EU member state needs to pick. The Netherlands is therefore *going to* change time zones at some point. They will likely choose to stick either to permanent summer time (in which case they'd be at UTC+2 permanently, vs. their current situation where they are at UTC+2 in summer and UTC+1 in winter, with, notably, different dates when the switch happens vs. New York!), or stay on winter time, i.e. UTC+1 forever.

Let's say they choose to stick to winter time forever.

The day the gavel slams down in the dutch parliament building enshrining into law that the dutch will no longer advance the clocks in march **is the day your appointment shifts by one hour**. After all, your barber is not going to go into their appointment book and shift all appointments by an hour. No, your appointment will remain on June 20th, 2025, at 11:00. If you have a running clock ticking down the seconds until your barber appointment, when that gavel comes down it should jump by 3600 seconds.

This belies the point: That barber appointment truly **is not** a singular moment in time. It's a human/political agreement that your appointment is when Amsterdam universally agrees it is currently June 20th, 2025, 11:00 – *and who knows when that moment will actually occur; it depends on political choices*.

So, you cannot 'solve' this by storing an instant in time, and it shows how the concept 'instant in time' and 'year/month/day hour:minute:second in a certain timezone' are **not quite interchangible**.

The correct data type for this concept is a `ZonedDateTime`. This represents a date time in human terms: year/month/day hour:second:minute, **and** the timezone. It doesn't shortcut by storing a moment in time in epochmillis or some such. If the gavel comes down and your JDK updates its timezone definitions, asking "how many seconds until my appointment" will **correctly** shift by 3600 seconds, which is what you want.

Because this is for appointments and it doesn't make sense to store just the time of an appointment but not the date, there is no such thing as a `ZonedDate` or a `ZonedTime`. Unlike the first thing which comes in 3 flavours (`LocalDateTime`, `LocalDate`, and `LocalTime`), there's only `ZonedDateTime`.

### The universe/log time

Imagine you are writing a computer system that logs that an event occurred.

That event, naturally, has a timestamp associated with it. Turns out that due to severe political upheaval, the laws of the land decide that *retrospectively* the country has been in a different timezone than what you thought when the event occurred. Applying the same logic as the barber's case (where the actual moment in time jumps by 3600 seconds when the gavel comes down) **is incorrect**. The timestamp represents a moment in time when a thing happened, not an appointment in a ledger. It should not jump by 3600.

Timezone really has no purpose here. The point of storing 'timestamp' for a log event is so you know when it happened, it doesn't matter *where* it happened (or if it does, that is fundamentally a separate notion).

The correct data type for this is `java.time.Instant`. An instant doesn't even know about time zones at all, and isn't a human concept. This is 'computery time' - stored as millis since an agreed upon epoch (midnight, UTC, 1970, new years), no timezone information is necessary or sane here. Naturally there is no time-only or date-only variant, this thing doesn't even really know what 'date' is - some fancypants human concept that computery time is not concerned with in the slightest.

### Conversions

You can trivially go from a `ZonedDateTime` to an `Instant`. There's a no-args method that does it. But note:

1. Create a ZonedDateTime.
2. Store it someplace.
3. Convert it to an Instant, store that too.
4. Update your JDK and get new time zone info
5. Load the ZDT.
6. Convert it to an Instant a second time.
7. Compare the 2 ZDTs and the 2 instants.

Results in different results: The 2 instants would not be the same, but the ZDTs are the same. The ZDT represents the appointment line in the barber's book (which never changed - 2025 june 20th, 11:00), the instant represents the moment in time that you are supposed to show up which did change.

If you store your barber's appointment as a `java.time.Instant` object, **you will be an hour late to your barber's appointment**. That's why it's important to store things as what they are. A barber's appointment is a `ZonedDateTime`. storing it as anything else would be wrong.

Conversions are rarely truly simple. There is no one way to convert one thing to another - you need to think of what these things represent, what the conversion implies, and then follow suit.

Example: You are writing a logging system. The backend parts store log events into a database of some sort, and the frontend parts read this database and show the log events to an admin user for review. Because the admin user is a human being, they want to see it in terms they understand, say, the time and date according to UTC (it's a programmer, they tend to like that sort of thing).

The logging system's storage should be storing the `Instant` concept: Epoch millis, and without timezone because that is irrelevant.

The frontend should read these *as `Instant`* (it is always a bad idea to do silent conversions!) - then consider how to render this to the user, figure out that the user wants these as local-to-UTC, and thus you would then on the fly, for each event to be printed to screen, convert the Instant to a ZonedDateTime in the zone the user wants, and from there to a LocalDateTime which you then render (because the user probably does not want to see `UTC` on every line, their screen estate is limited).

It would be incorrect to store the timestamps as UTC ZonedDateTimes, and even more wrong to store them as LocalDateTimes derived by asking for the current LocalDT in UTC as the event happens and then storing that. Mechanically all these things would *work* but the data types are all wrong. And that will complicate matters. Imagine the user actually wants to see the log event in Europe/Amsterdam time.

### A note about timezones

The world is more complicated than a handful of timezones. For example, almost all of mainland europe is currently 'CET' (Central European Time), but some think that refers to european winter time (UTC+1), some thing that refers to the current state in central europe: UTC+1 in winter, UTC+2 in summer. (There's also CEST, Central European Summer Time, which means UTC+2 and isn't ambiguous). When EU countries start applying the new law to get rid of daylight savings, its likely e.g. The Netherlands on the west edge of the CET zone picks a different time than Poland on the eastern edge. Hence, 'all of central europe' is far too broad. 3-letter acronyms also are by no means unique. Various countries use 'EST' to mean 'eastern standard time', it's not just the eastern USA for example.

Hence, the only proper way to represent timezone names is using strings like `Europe/Amsterdam` or `Asia/Singapore`. If you need to render these as `09:00 PST` for residents of the west coast of the USA, that's a rendering issue, so, write a rendering method that turns `America/Los_Angeles` into `PST`, which is an issue of localization, and has nothing to do with time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for nice explanations, voted up. By considering Spring Boot apps with the databases e.g. PostgreSQL and MySQL, can we say that? >>>

Comment: **1.** I could use `LocalDateTime` or `Instant` when I don't need to keep timezone and the app will only be used in the same place only ?

Comment: **2.** When we need to also keep time zone, then should we use `ZonedDateTime` ?

Comment: **3.** As far as I see, `Instant` can be used as timestamp instead of `LocalDateTime`, right?

Comment: @batman Using `LocalDateTime` for a log timestamp would be a horrible idea. `Instant` is the only correct type for such a thing.

Comment: The point is: _There is no correct answer here_ - because it depends on what the data you are trying to store _means_. Is it the time when an event occurred? `Instant` is perfect for the timestamp of a log message. It's an appointment at a GP office? `ZonedDateTime`; `LocalDateTime` is borderline acceptable if the system is fundamentally not designed to ever go beyond a single-timezone country borders.

Comment: Then, 'how do LocalDateTime, LocalTime, LocalDate, ZonedDateTime, and Instant map to databases' is its own really hairy problem. One core issue is that the JDBC API __gets this wrong__, but all modern DB engines (in fact, required by jDBC spec v5 if memory serves) do allow `.getObject(col, LocalDateTime.class)` for example, so you can avoid the broken `.getDate(col)`.

Comment: Thus trying to answer the question 'what to do in spring' requires knowing [A] the DB engine and what their take on date/time types is, [B] the JDBC driver and whether it does this right or messes it up (example, H2's messes it up - folks in Europe/Amsterdam storing birthdates on modern JVMs are screwed, speaking from experience here), [C] how spring translates DB stuff into JDBC. I don't know [C], I barely know A/B for postgres specifically.

Comment: Of course choosing the most proper one is based on the requirements, but I just would like to know the example scenarios when I decide to choose one of them. Based on your last comments, can we say that, it time zone is not important, then we can use either `LocaldateTime` or `Instant` (for more precisely stuffs e.g. logging). And when zone is a matter, then we can use `ZonedDateTime`, right?

Comment: No - you need to choose the type that properly represents what you have. If you are storing barber appointments in terms of `j.t.Instant` your code is wrong, even if it functions perfectly today. Timezone changes will mess you up, and your code is hard to read. Hence, 'but will this technically work' is an irrelevant question, and your insistence on an answer seems to indicate you don't understand the point here. _Every kind of time-related event_ has ONE correct data type of the 5 (LDT/LD/LT/ZDT/Instant).

Comment: Sorry, I did not considered the time differences in the same location. In this scene, which datetime types should I choose in general situations e.g. when keeping logs, when considering or not considering zone / daylight savings for the same location?

Comment: Log timestamps? `Instant`. Appointments (say, storing 'this doc wrote this note about this patient when they saw them in their office at moment-in-time Y') - ZonedDateTime. Birthdays? LocalDate.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the last comment also very useful

Comment: Now I know you are not supposed to thank people in comments on SO, but I'm an old timer and this is perhaps the best explanation of a very complex, confusing and often misinterpreted topic I have ever seen. Fluent, clear, to the point, and focusing on the concepts which is what matters and what people most often get wrong. Just superb. So thank you for this! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

The [Answer by rzwitserloot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75493748/642706) is correct and wise. In addition, here is a summary of the various types. For more info, see [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32443004/642706) on a similar Question.

> 1. To keep time precisely as timestamp (I am not sure if Instant is the best option)?

If you want to track a moment, a specific point on the timeline:

- `Instant`
  A moment as seen with an offset-from-UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. This class is the basic building-block of the *java.time* framework.
- `OffsetDateTime`
  A moment as seen with a particular offset, some number of hours-minutes-seconds ahead of, or behind, the temporal meridian of UTC.
- `ZonedDateTime`
  A moment as seen with a particular time zone. A time zone is a named history of the past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region, as decided by their politicians.

If you want to track just the date and time-of-day, without the context of an offset or time zone, use `LocalDateTime`. This class does *not* represent a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline.

> 2. For normal cases when I just need date and time

If you are absolutely sure that you want only a date with time-of-day, but do not need the context of an offset or time zone, use `LocalDateTime`.

> using LocalDateTime with UTC

That is a contradiction, and makes no sense. A `LocalDateTime` class has no concept of UTC, nor any concept of offset-from-UTC or time zone.

> Spring Data JPA

The [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) 4.2+ specification maps [SQL standard data types](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/data-type.php#DATETIME) to Java classes.

- `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` columns map to `OffsetDateTime` in Java.
- `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` columns map to `LocalDateTime` in Java.
- `DATE` columns map to `LocalDate`.
- `TIME WITHOUT TIME ZONE` columns map to `LocalTime`.

The SQL standard also mentions `TIME WITH TIME ZONE`, but this type is meaningless (just think about it!). The SQL committee has never explained what they had in mind, as far as I know. If you *must* use this type, Java defines the `ZoneOffset` class to match.

Note that [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) does *not* map any SQL types to `Instant` nor `ZonedDateTime`. You can easily convert to/from the mapped type `OffsetDateTime`.

```
Instant instant = myOffsetDateTime.toInstant() ;
OffsetDateTime myOffsetDateTime = instant.atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

… and:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = myOffsetDateTime.atZoneSameInstant( myZoneId ) ;
OffsetDateTime odt = zdt.toOffsetDateTime() ;  // The offset in use at that moment in that zone.
OffsetDateTime odt = zdt.toInstant().atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;  // Offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC.
```

> I also consider the TimeZone

The `TimeZone` class is part of the terrible legacy date-time classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes. Replaced by `ZoneId` and `ZoneOffset`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for nice explanations, voted up. By considering Spring Boot apps with the databases e.g. PostgreSQL and MySQL, can we say that? >>>

Comment: **1.** I could use `LocalDateTime` or `Instant` when I don't need to keep timezone and the app will only be used in the same place only ?

Comment: **2.** When we need to also keep time zone, then should we use `ZonedDateTime` ?

Comment: **3.** As far as I see, `Instant` can be used as timestamp instead of `LocalDateTime`, right?

Comment: @user21099360  RE: # 1 … `Instant` is fundamentally different from `LocalDateTime`. The first represents a moment, a point on the timeline. The second does not. A for abusing `LocalDateTime` to pretend it represents a moment, why? You gain nothing but ambiguity and likely an eventual nightmare of screwed-up data. Why not use the appropriate data type?

Comment: @user21099360 RE: # 2 … Yes. Thus the name, `ZonedDateTime`. Represents a moment as seen in the wall clock/calendar used by the people of a particular region.

Comment: @user21099360 RE: # 3 … `Instant` represents a moment as seen with an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from the temporal meridian of UTC. This class is the basic building block of the *java.time* framework. In contrast, `LocalDateTime` is *not* a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline, and cannot serve as a timestamp. This is not complicated: A date and a time-of-day alone is inherently ambiguous. Just think it through. Is “noon on the 23rd of January 2024” noon in Tokyo, noon in Toulouse, or noon in Toledo?