# Java Play Framework Form Binding fails for Java 8 LocalDateTime with validation error.invalid

Tags: java, playframework, jackson, jackson-databind

Working on application based on Java play framework, task is to replace legacy date java.util.Date to java8 java.time.LocalDatetime in the whole application. But there is issue with the form binding when a Date attribute changed to LocalDateTime .

FE send the data as

```
{"dob": "2023-12-05T00:00:00+01:00}
```

Form is like that

```
 @Data
    @Constraints.Validate
    public static class StudentForm implements Constraints.Validatable<List<ValidationError>> {

        @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = ISO_DATE_TIME_WITH_OFFSET_FORMAT,
                timezone = DEFAULT_TIME_ZONE)
        @Formats.DateTime(pattern = ISO_DATE_TIME_WITH_OFFSET_FORMAT)
        //NEW CODE
        private LocalDateTime dob;
 
}
```

in the old code dob is a java.util.Date object

```
 @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = ISO_DATE_TIME_WITH_OFFSET_FORMAT,
                timezone = DEFAULT_TIME_ZONE)
        @Formats.DateTime(pattern = ISO_DATE_TIME_WITH_OFFSET_FORMAT)
 private Date dob;
```

Request is received in the following controller

```
public class StudentController extends Controller {

  public CompletionStage<Result> create(Http.Request request) {

    var form = formFactory.form(StudentForm.class).bindFromRequest(request);
        if (form.hasErrors())
            return completedFuture(badRequest(error(form.errors())));
 
    }
}
```

gives validation error

```
 "error.invalid"
```

even tried with following annotations in the form but still no succes

```
 @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
        @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX")
        private LocalDateTime dob;
```

date Deserialization during the form binding failing , Its really hard to debug and see whats happening inside Playframwork

So how to bind a java 8 LocalDateTime in the form?

Comment: You probably want to use `Instant` rather than `LocalDateTime` for which a timezone doesn't make sense. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437550/whats-the-difference-between-instant-and-localdatetime