# Which Java class to use to store creation timestamp in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-time

I'm developing a web application. When users sign up, their registration datetime needs to be stored accurately in the database and later displayed in a frontend viewed by site administrators.

I want to ensure that the displayed datetime is correct **from the perspective of the user viewing the page, regardless of their timezone**.

If a user registers at midday in New York, someone in London might see "user registered at 5pm today". This includes daylight saving time if applicable.

In Spring boot I use this annotation for storing the creation timestamp, and I am trying to determine if the class used here is appropriate:

```
@CreationTimestamp
@Column(name = "created_at")
public OffsetDateTime created_at;
```

But thinking about this I am very confused. Do I need to store a ZonedDateTime, or can I just actually store a timestamp (Instant) and then add the zone information later depending on who is making the request? Using the example above, this would be:

```
ZonedDateTime responseZonedDateTime = instant.atZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/London"));
```

The timezone here would come from the request handler, e.g.

```
@GetMapping
public String getUser(TimeZone timezone) { }
```

This seems like a lot of work and maybe there is a better solution?

(If this is relevant I am using PostgreSQL and the column type is `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Java's `Instant` for saving the timestamp. There is no need to save the timezone in the use-case you are describing. For displaying the timestamp in the timezone of the requesting user, you can use client libraries which are able to convert a UTC timestamp to the client timezone (i.e. dayjs, momentjs etc.).

Saving the timezone only becomes relevant if you ever want to display/know the time of the user registering in their timezone.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Any ideas why in documentation and examples the OffsetDateTime and LocalDateTime is used so often? Any reasons to store this additional information?

Comment: I can recommend this answer which goes in-depth for the different data types and when they are useful/applicable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32443004/1386873

Comment: *Any ideas why in documentation* - timestamp is ending 2038: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem

Comment: Timestamp isn't ending 2038. Timestamps saved in signed 32-bit integers are overflowing/ending. Java's `Instant` already uses `long` to store the timestamp.

Comment: @user372786 I think LocalDateTime is often used by people because they don't understand it and think it means local to some time zone when it really means without any time zone.

Comment: Postgres' `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` is misleading name IMO - as based on that, one would assume, that it stores time zone information. But it doesn't. It's converts the input value (that can contain offset) to instant-represented in UTC. Then when you retrieve it from database, it will automatically convert it to "your" (based on session). For your use case, I'd use `WITHOUT TIME ZONE` and do the conversion to instant in your java app. Same with retrieving, you will get it in UTC and then do the conversion in the app based on target timezone.