Which datatype to use at JPA entity to store and retrieve date using java 8
I am using java 8 version in my application, I have confused to use java date classes like java.util.Date and java.time.LocalDate at entity and dto level.
Before java 8, we used to use either java.sql.Date or java.util.Date but in java 8 introduced LocalDate so can I use LocalDate for both entity and dto class.
My date format should be either dd-MM-yyyy or dd/MM/yyyy, dto is used as Rest API request body and enity as we know this is the model to maps with database.
Can I use LocalDate for both entity and dto, in the database table column datatype is Date.

"Can I use LocalDate for both entity and dto" Yes, you can since JPA 2.2.

@RobbyCornelissen I can use entity and dto for same data type i.e LocalDate that should be fine right ?

What are you asking that is not already answered by my previous comment?

Here is a good overview https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437550/whats-the-difference-between-instant-and-localdatetime

Yes, this is one of the many advantages of java.time, the modern Java date and time API: we can use the same type everywhere and have no need to convert to or from java.sql types. You are completely right, in your case LocalDate is the correct type.

Definitely you can and should use LocalDate class. Also you should use annotation
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")

over a your variable declaration or over a getter method for it. Here is a very good question with excellent answer that deals with the same topic but just for ZonedDateTime class: Spring Data JPA - ZonedDateTime format for json serialization

You can and should use java.time.LocalDate. The java.time package was introduced in Java 8 and is designed to replace the old java.util.Date and java.sql.Date classes.
